# Text fuzzy, when I use French characters

Tags: fonts, french

I tried to resolve my problem in many ways but nothing worked well.

I have downloaded a LaTeX template that helps with my work; it uses this package

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

But because I write in French, many characters like **é** and **à** don't appear.  So I add some package [that provides them] but, when I add that package, the text becomes fuzzy.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} % to be included when using \usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
```

Is there any way to resolve this, i.e. un-fuzz-ify the characters?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) it sounds like the package you added calls in fonts that are present only as bitmaps.  someone else may be able to tell you which fonts those are, and whether type 1 (outline) fonts are available.

Comment: The easiest solution is to add `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: As the others said: you are using bitmap fonts and you want vector fonts. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291

Comment: @egreg and all,   thanks that resolve my probleme is very helpfull thanks a lot,

Comment: a salutary lesson.  i have recently thought of removing the answer on “fuzzy fonts” from the [uk tex faq](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fuzzy-T1) (there is at least one other).  i had imagined that “people don’t get that any more” ...

Comment: @wasteofspace: somewhat related, [by modern standards CM-Super really isn't that huge anymore.](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=type1T1)