# \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} makes the font look awful in Google Chrome

Tags: pdftex, typography

I am using MikTex, and reduced the problem to the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % this causes the problem

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor .....
\end{document}
```

If I compile this document using `pdflatex test.tex` and then open the resulting PDF in Google Chrome it looks like this:

[image]

Here's without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

[image]

Needless to say, the latter looks a lot better. What could be causing this?

Comment: It looks like your document is using bitmapped fonts... see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski That was indeed it thanks, would it be possible to close this as a duplicate, or should I delete my question?