# Problem T1 fontenc and microtype?

Tags: miktex, font-encodings, microtype

I had to reinstall Windows on my pc, and therefore Latex too. It worked perfectly well before, and I don't understand why I have a problem now (I reinstall the complete miktex distribution).

Here is the code (the original document is much bigger, but you can see the problem with that part) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsmath,amstext,amsfonts}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{boiboites}

\newtheorem{thm}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]
\newboxedtheorem[titleboxcolor = white]{defn}{D\'efinition}{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
Soient $n$ un entier naturel et $a$ et $b$ deux entiers relatifs. On dit $a$ est congru \`a $b$ modulo $n$ s'il existe un entier relatif $k$ tel que $a=b+kn$. \\ 
On note $a \equiv b [n]$.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Boiboites is a package that allows to box theorem and that you cand find on this forum, or here http://snouffy.free.fr/blog-fr/index.php/post/2009/09/30/Des-jolies-boites-en-LaTeX-pour-encadrer-les-th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes

When I build the document, I have this error and no output document :

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv
```

But if I remove the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, it works fine, or the same if I remove the microtype package.

I downloaded the most recent packages, checked for available update but all of them are up-to-date. Is there anyone that can solve my problem ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Actually I had already the package cm-super (to avoid problem like that I generally install all the packages !) and I still had a problem.
Then I added the package lmodern, and it fixed my problem.
Do you know why I had to do this now, whereas it worked fine before ?

Comment: I think it's a common problem with MiKTeX that it doesn't automatically update the font maps: try `initexmf --admin --mkmaps`

Comment: @egreg *If* the problem is with the maps (which I don't know) than normally this means that they are user maps around and then one would have to update them without the `--admin` switch. And miktex normally *does* update the (default) font maps.

Comment: @egreg Is this a Linux command ? Because I am using Windows. And actually I forced Miktex to look for available update (with the package manager)

Comment: @antoine That's to issued in a Windows command window, I'm not expert in it, sorry.

Comment: @antoine: Run your example without microtype and then check in the log-file the location of pdftex.map. If it resides in your user account you must update it by running the command `updmap` in a command line. Regarding updates: Did you check with both update managers?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You were right, the pdftex.map is indeed in my user account, and I updated it with your command. I did compile again and it works now !! You talked about two update manager ? I tried with the package manager, and directly with Maintenance > update

Comment: If you have a multiuser installation of miktex then there should be two set of maintenance tools: e.g. Update manager and Update manager (admin), similar for the package manager.

Comment: Yes indeed. I use the admin's one.