# Pixelated PDF output

Tags: fonts, lyx, pdf

The PDF output of my LyX documents is rather pixelated as can be seen on the image. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.2.12)  14 FEB 2015 13:56
entering extended mode
**newfile1.tex
(newfile1.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\lualatex\luainputenc\luainputenc.sty"
Package: luainputenc 2010/11/19 v0.973 inputenc package for LuaTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2014/09/25 3.9l Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)) (newfile1.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
 [1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (newfile1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1073 strings out of 493698
 11957 string characters out of 3141988
 68529 words of memory out of 3000000
 4434 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7500 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,4n,23p,176b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\User
s\Valdrin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecbx1000.
pk> <C:\Users\Valdrin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi6
00\ecbx2074.pk> <C:\Users\Valdrin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jkna
ppen\ec\dpi600\ecbx1440.pk> <C:\Users\Valdrin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk
\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on newfile1.pdf (1 page, 9261 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 40 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce it in order to address the issue. Can you provide us with such information?

Comment: This comes up from time to time. I don't understand why the problem is predominantly reported by Windows users (perhaps because MikTeX does not install cm-super by default?). In any case, do you have the cm-super package installed? In addition to @Werner 's comment, can you please post your log file (I think this will tell you whether you do not have a certain font and those a bitmap font was substituted for it).

Comment: I have edited the first post and added the log. The same thing happens when i use TeXmaker, so it might be a MikTeX problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Further reading: [Latin Modern vs cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390/16967)

Answer (score 1):

It seems, as stated by @scottkosty, to be related to the font, probably Computer Modern. So, just change it.

In Lyx, go to `Document` > `Settings...` > `Fonts` and change it to something that suits you better, like TeX Gyre Bonum.

[image]

Comment: Changing fonts changes the apperacance (given by templates) and should not be done. This issue can be repaired by installing packages without editing the tex-file, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546882/110064

Comment: Excellent cross-link. Pro cross-link.