# Using helvet, fontenc packes with ttfamily gives pixelated font

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, typewriter, helvetica

I use Helvetica as the font for my document (`helvet` package). Now I need some parts to be printed in typwriter face, e.g. via `\ttfamily`. However, as long as I use the `fontenc` package with the `T1` option the text generated turns out to be pixelated (upper text normal, lower `\ttfamily`).

With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:
[image: using T1 fonts]

Without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:
[image: not using T1 fonts]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
% required to use sans-serif in normal text
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} & <-- comment/uncomment this line

\begin{document}
\noindent
normal: {I'm Batman and Superman} \\
ttfamily: {\ttfamily I'm Batman and Superman}
\end{document}
```

I assume it's related to the fact that `helvet` has no serif-fonts, but `\ttfamily` tries to select one. Is there any way around this? I thought about redefining `\ttfamily` with (another?) monospace font, but couldn't yet figure out how exactly to do this properly.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the mix, before `\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}`.

Comment: I don't see pixels on Adobe Reader (Linux version) even up to 6400% magnification, regardless whether `fontenc` is used or not

Comment: Let me guess: you're using MiKTeX. If so, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically This has nothing to do with Helvetica.

Comment: @Christian: Maybe egreg's comment solved that, I get pixels in Adobe Reader (Windows), Sumatra (Windows) and Okular (Linux).
I am indeed using MiKTeX and just installed this package, so far nothing improved. But Stevens comment helped, and I figured I could use any T1 font.
Regarding the duplicate, I found that question, but figured it didn't help me with my problem.

Comment: @Timm: Hm, well, I can't test this with MikTeX, but I get no pixels as well in Okular under Linux.

Comment: @egreg: I installed it, updated all formats in the settings manager, but nothing changed. I would answer this question with Stevens suggestion now, or you (all) could decide it's a duplicate after all.

Comment: After the installation of cm-super you need to activate the map files, run `updmap` on a command line.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: you get pixels if cm-super is not installed (which is the case of a basic miktex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I see... but I won't uninstall `cm-super` just for this purpose now ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You could simply disable its map file `\pdfmapfile{-cm-super-t1.map}`.