Faded pdf with same code
I excute the same code with the same preambule on the same machine with the same engine (pdflatex):
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[english]{babel}

...

The only difference is that first time I run it on complete MiKTeX installation (all pakages are installed) and the second time I install only basic packages + some minimum requirements for my project.
Everything complies fine, but the pdf output in the second case looks faded.


I try to understand, what packages are required specifically to fix this issue.
Appreciate any help.

Have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically helps

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! Everything works fine!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, that link solves the problem.
