# fontenc vs inputenc

Tags: font-encodings, input-encodings

I just don't seem to get it. So I come from the german speaking part of Switzerland and naturally I need ä ü ö a lot when I write german texts. So in LaTeX I have the option to go via

`"a "u "o`

which isn't really comfortable, or I can use an additional package. So now the confusion starts.
I can use either

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

or

`\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

So now if I create a new document and save it as a latin-1 encoded .tex file it seems it doesn't matter which option I chose they both work. Now why should I pick one over the other or use both? Which problems could occur (Do they occur if I use the same .tex file on another OS depending on which option I have chosen?)?

If I save the .tex encoded as lets say the mac os latin then the first option compiles but shows the wrong characters for the ä ü ö's.
Is it then like latex maps the ä according to the latin1 to a character and since the document is encoded as something different than latin1 then gets encoded to something different again?

So if the last 2 paragraphs have been confusing (mainly because I'm confused) the main question is: What does fontenc what inputenc doesn't do and vice versa?

Comment: had problems with [utf8]{inputenc}, using lualatex.exe fixed it

Answer (score 283, accepted):

The two packages address different problems.

1. `inputenc` allows the user to *input* accented characters directly from the keyboard;
2. `fontenc` is oriented to *output*, that is, what fonts to use for printing characters.

The two packages are not connected, though it is best to call `fontenc` first and then `inputenc`.

With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you choose an output font encoding that has support for the accented characters used by the most widespread European languages (German, French, Italian, Polish and others), which is important because otherwise TeX would not correctly hyphenate words containing accented letters.

With `\usepackage[<encoding>]{inputenc}` you can directly input accented and other characters. What's important is that `<encoding>` matches the encoding with which the file has been written and this depends on your operating system and the settings of your text editor.

If calling only

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

you seem to get correct output, then your files are probably encoded with Latin-1 (also called ISO 8859-1), but beware that the correspondence is *not* complete: for example, typing `ß` you'd get `SS` in output, which is obviously incorrect. Thus your editor might be set up for Latin-1 and so the correct call should be

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

How do the packages work? Let's do the example for these two encodings and the character `ä`.

First of all one must remember that TeX knows *nothing* about file encodings: all it really sees is the character number.

1. When you type `ä` in an editor set up for Latin-1, the machine stores character number 228.
2. When TeX reads the file it finds the character number 228 and the macros of `inputenc` transform this into `\"a`.
3. Now `fontenc` comes into action; the command `\"` has an associated table of the known accented characters the font has available, and `ä` is among these, so the sequence `\"a` is transformed into the command "print character 228" in the current (T1-encoded) font.

In this case the two coincide. This is not the case, for instance, of `ß`:

1. The machine stores character number 223
2. The macros of `inputenc` change this into `\ss`
3. `fontenc` transforms this into "print character 255" (where T1 encoded fonts have a ß character).

### UTF-8

The situation is a bit different when `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is used (and the file is UTF-8 encoded, of course). When the text editor shows `ä` or `ß`, the file actually contains two byte sequences, respectively `<C3><A4>` and `<C3><9F>`

The first byte is a *prefix* that contains some information, the main one is that it introduces a two byte character. Now `inputenc` makes all legal prefixes active, so `<C3>` behaves like a macro; its definition is to look at the next character and then interpret, according to Unicode rules, the whole pair and transforms it into the corresponding code point, respectively U+00E4 and U+00DF.

Other prefixes announce three or four byte combinations, but the behavior is essentially the same: instead of one character more, two or three others are absorbed and the translation into a code point is performed.

In `ot1enc.dfu` and `t1enc.dfu` we find

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DF}{\ss}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\"a}
```

Oh, wait! There's something more! Yes, in this case `inputenc` interacts with `fontenc` (which it doesn't for other input encodings): for every loaded encoding, the corresponding `.dfu` file (Unicode definitions) is read before the document starts. This is the reason why I prefer to always load `fontenc` before `inputenc` (though not really necessary).

Those declarations provide the necessary setup: the combinations `<C3><A4>` and `<C3><9F>` get translated into `\"a` and `\ss` respectively and everything works from now on as described for `latin1`.

### *Caveat*

Here's another issue that can pop up at times (see [Available Characters with iso-8859-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331151/available-characters-with-iso-8859-1)). The Latin-1 encoding provides at slot `0xA5` (decimal 165) the yen character. According to the description above, the `latin1` option to `inputenc` defines the `\textyen` translation for this, but the T1 output encoding reserves no slot for this, so inputting `¥` results in a runtime LaTeX error. One has to load a package providing a default output for `\textyen`, for instance `textcomp`. It would be the same with the `utf8` input encoding.

Only characters covered by the output encoding or that are given a suitable rendering in terms of it can be safely input.

Comment: I really liked this explanation, I hope you don't mind me giving a German translation (http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1644)

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Not at all! The `inputenc`-`fontenc` problem has often bitten many users.

Comment: I read a while back that textcomp became obsolete/deprecated. Does this answer need an update?

Comment: @thymaro No, the package is neither deprecated nor obsolete

Comment: I wanted to look at the pkg documentation of `textcomp` and just remembered where I'd read that... I guess somebody with power to do so should review the page https://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp, if `textcomp` isn't obsolete. I'm getting mixed messages, right there ;)

Comment: @thymaro The text seems clear, but the title can indeed be confusing.

Comment: @thymaro basically that link states the package has been included into TeX/LaTex so the separate package is obsolete and not the content.

Comment: @mcheema oh ok now I get it. I'll never need to install it, but still need to load it to use its functionality. Is that correct?

Comment: @thymaro thats correct and only if you use pdflatex as the answer below explains

Comment: Why did you say "though it is best to call `fontenc` first and then `inputenc`"?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé It's an old habit of mine; some years ago, I discovered that the reverse order had some problems when Cyrillic was involved. The problem has long been solved, but still I think this is cleaner, because `inputenc` *needs* to know the loaded encodings (there's a list read at begin document anyhow).

Comment: Has something changed with the new April 2018 kernel? In particular about the loading of the `.dfu` files?

Comment: @campa Just that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can be omitted if the file is UTF-8 encoded; `fontenc` is still necessary.

Comment: Could you explain or provide a link explaining what `.dfu` is? You lost me on that part. 
Also, why is `\ss` not printed as `ss` with UTF-8 (see last paragraph in section UTF-8)?

Comment: @Lukas For every font encoding loaded in the document, say T1 for instance, LaTeX will load the file `t1enc.dfu` that provides definitions for the characters, so U+00DF will be translated into `\ss` and so will print ß (not `ss`, because `\ss` is a command).

Comment: Why haven't I been taught this ages ago? Beats me :-)

Answer (score 98):

Yes, you are confused. You should use *both* packages with `pdflatex` or a different approach with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

### `pdflatex`

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

### `xelatex`

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

### `lualatex`

```
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

Or in a complete document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
   \ifXeTeX
     \usepackage{fontspec}
   \else 
     \usepackage{luatextra}
   \fi
   \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
äöüßÄÖÜ

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

This assumes that your input is `utf8`, but you should do this anyway. It's 2012, after all.

See also:

- [Why you should use T1 with `pdflatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677/5763)
- [An introduction to XeTeX](http://www.dante.de/DTK/Ausgaben/2008-3.pdf)

Comment: lmodern is not useful for XeLaTeX? Why?

Comment: @ppr: It is, but with Lua/XeLaTeX you don't use the `lmodern` package but `fontspec`.

Comment: The [xltxtra package documentation page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltxtra?lang=en) says it is deprecated, and to use only [fontspec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) instead.

Comment: egreg's answer is great as an explanation (I upvoted it, of course), but I also like yours, because of its "directive" tone (sometimes I just want to be told what to do).

Comment: Is `\usepackage{lmodern}` mandatory in `pdflatex`? I want to use `txfonts` but they are disabled in presence of `lmodern`.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: No. It's only useful if you want to use a font similar to Computer Modern.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Hi, MartinSchröder. I can not understand `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` after reading the doc. What does it do?

Comment: Other comments at tex.stackexchange say you just need to add \usepackage{fontenc} . What's the difference between than and your solution ? (with LuaTeX)

Comment: @skan I was wondering the same thing, I guess when the answer was written in 2012 fontspec did not work with LuaLaTex.

Comment: @Erik `luatextra` loads `fontspec` in addition to some other packages (including `fixltx2e` which is obsolete nowadays). So one shouldn't load `luatextra` but `fontspec` in LuaTeX.

Comment: The link to "An Intro do XeTeX" no longer works. Are you able to update it?

Answer (score 27):

You need `inputenc` to specify the character encoding used in your input file if it is not ascii. So latin1 (or more general and modern, utf8).

`fontenc` specifies the encoding used in the fonts. this is (more or less) independent of the input encoding. Classical TeX uses Tex-specific font encodings such as "T1" for 8-bit fonts suitable for "latin1" languages.

Conceptually the input and font encodings would be totally independent but they are related in that you need a font encoding that includes the characters in the desired language and (regrettably) hyphenation patterns used to hyphenate words in the document are tied to the font encoding due to the way TeX works.

Comment: `inputenc` is only needed with `pdftex`, not with `xetex` or `luatex`.

Answer (score 23):

To understand this, you need to realize that TeX is a "translator" that translates its input (the text you wrote) into output (PDF, or PS file).  Accordingly the encodings of the input and the encoding of the output are two quite different things.

`inputenc` tells TeX the encoding of your `.tex` file.  It can be `latin1`, or `utf8`, or `koi8r`, or whatever.  This is the encoding you set in the editor you use to write the text.

`fontenc` tells TeX which encoding you want in the *output* file. Mostly it affects things like hyphenation.  It depends on the fonts you select, since the name.

Comment: So `inputenc` is basically important for the portability of the .tex file whereas `fontenc` is important for the output of said .tex file?

Comment: @Philipp: Basically, yes. _Please_ read l2kurz/lshort.

Comment: This is _only_ relevant if you are using `latex` or `pdflatex`. It's 2012: You should use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, which can handle unicode input without problems.