# Create a mapping for transliteration from cyrillic to latin in LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, cyrillic, mapping

I created a `.map` file for Cyrillic to Latin transliteration as in [using xetex for automatic transliteration of Cyrillic letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/using-xetex-for-automatic-transliteration-of-cyrillic-letters)

I placed the `cyrillic-to-latin.tec` file in the folder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

\setmainfont[Mapping=cyrillic-to-latin]{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\ifxetex
    This is XeTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is LuaTeX
\fi\fi

Hello, world

Здравствуй, Мир

\end{document}
```

The thing works perfectly running XeLaTeX, but the mapping system is simply ignored by LuaLaTeX.

Compiled with XeLaTeX
[image]

Compiled with LuaLaTeX
[image]

How to force LuaLaTeX in using the desired font mapping?

Note: as  @Michal.h21 asks, I put the .map file I personally use for transliteration with italian rules:

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "Cyrillic-to-Latin"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET


U+0410 <> U+0041  ; A
U+0411 <> U+0042  ; B
U+0412 <> U+0056  ; V
U+0413 <> U+0047  ; G
U+0414 <> U+0044  ; D
U+0415 <> U+0045  ; E
U+0416 <> U+017D  ; Ž
U+0417 <> U+005A  ; Z
U+0418 <> U+0049  ; I
U+041A <> U+004B  ; K
U+041B <> U+004C  ; L
U+041C <> U+004D  ; M
U+041D <> U+004E  ; N
U+041E <> U+004F  ; O
U+041F <> U+0050  ; P
U+0420 <> U+0052  ; R
U+0421 <> U+0053  ; S
U+0422 <> U+0054  ; T
U+0423 <> U+0055  ; U
U+0424 <> U+0046  ; F
U+0426 <> U+0043  ; C
U+0427 <> U+010C  ; Č
U+0428 <> U+0160  ; Š
U+042D <> U+0116  ; Ė
U+042E <> U+004A U+0075  ; Ju
U+042F <> U+004A U+0061  ; Ja
U+0401 <> U+00CB  ; Ë
U+0430 <> U+0061  ; a
U+0431 <> U+0062  ; b
U+0432 <> U+0076  ; v
U+0433 <> U+0067  ; g
U+0434 <> U+0064  ; d
U+0435 <> U+0065  ; e
U+0436 <> U+017E  ; ž
U+0437 <> U+007A  ; z
U+0438 <> U+0069  ; i
U+0439 <> U+006A  ; j
U+043A <> U+006B  ; k
U+043B <> U+006C  ; l
U+043C <> U+006D  ; m
U+043D <> U+006E  ; n
U+043E <> U+006F  ; o
U+043F <> U+0070  ; p
U+0440 <> U+0072  ; r
U+0441 <> U+0073  ; s
U+0442 <> U+0074  ; t
U+0443 <> U+0075  ; u
U+0444 <> U+0066  ; f
U+0446 <> U+0063  ; c
U+0447 <> U+010D  ; č
U+0448 <> U+0161  ; š
U+044D <> U+0117  ; ė
U+044E <> U+006A U+0075  ; ju
U+044F <> U+006A U+0061  ; ja
U+0451 <> U+00EB  ; ë
U+0456 <> U+0069  ; i
U+0406 <> U+0049  ; I
U+0454 <> U+006A U+0065  ; je
U+0468 <> U+004A U+0065  ; Je
U+0425 <> U+0043 U+0068 ; Ch
U+0445 <> U+0063 U+0068 ; ch
U+0418 <> U+0049  ; I
U+0429 <> U+0160  U+010D ; Šč
U+042A <> U+0027  ; '
U+042B <> U+0059  ; Y
U+042C <> U+2019  ; '
U+0449 <> U+0161  U+010D ; šč
U+044A <> U+2019  ; '
U+044B <> U+0079  ; y
U+044C <> U+2019  ; '
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit 10/2017**

Here is a new version of the Lua script. It generates the code for Luaotfload, instead of the font feature file, which is not supported anymore. It has also new option `--back`, which creates mapping in the opposite direction, like from Cyrillic to Latin in our example.

The script is named `maptolua.lua`:

```lua
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"
local lapp = require "lapp-mk4"
local uchar = unicode.utf8.char
local args

local function load_glyph_list(filename)
  local t = {}
  for line in io.lines(filename) do
    local glyph, code = line:match("([^;]+);([A-Fa-f0-9]+)")
    if glyph then
      code = string.upper(code)
      -- print(code, glyph)
      t[code] = glyph
    end
  end
  return t
end

local function load_map_file(mapfile, glyph_list)
  local glyph_list = glyph_list or {}
  local parse_codepoints = function(s)
    local t = {}
    local s = string.upper(s)
    for x in s:gmatch("U%+([0-9A-F]+)") do
      t[#t+1] = glyph_list[x] or "undefined"
    end
    return t
  end
  local get_chars = function(s)
    local t = {}
    for x in s:gmatch("U%+([0-9A-F]+)") do
      t[#t+1] = string.format('"%s"', uchar(tonumber(x, 16)))
    end
    return t
  end
  local t = {liga = {}, gsub = {}, ccmp= {}}
  for line in io.lines(mapfile) do
    -- search for 
    local lookup, replace = line:match("([^%<]+)<>([^%;]+)")
    if args.back then -- we can create reverse mapping from the map file
      lookup, replace = replace, lookup
    end
    -- process lines which define mappings
    if lookup then
      -- convert strings with unicode codepoints to tables with glyph names
      -- local lookups = parse_codepoints(lookup)
      local lookups = get_chars(lookup)
      -- local replaces = parse_codepoints(replace)
      local replaces = get_chars(replace)
      -- print(table.concat(lookups, ";"), "+", table.concat(replaces, ";"))
      local newt = {lookups = lookups, replaces = replaces}
      if #lookups > 1 then
        table.insert(t.liga, newt)
      elseif #replaces > 1 then
        table.insert(t.ccmp, newt)
      else 
        table.insert(t.gsub, newt)
      end
    end
  end
  return t
end

local function print_fea_file(script, language,  maptable)
  local function print_feature(feature, name, typ, key, value) 
    -- the field must be only one character long
    print("fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {")
    print(string.format("\tname='%s',", name))
    print(string.format("\ttype='%s',", typ))
    print("\tdata={")
    for _, entry in ipairs(maptable[feature]) do
      local field = entry[key][1]
      local result = entry[value]
      if #result > 1 then
        local t = {}
        for _, s in ipairs(result) do
          t[#t+1] = string.format("%s", s)
        end
        result = "{" .. table.concat(t, ",") .. "}"
      else
        result = string.format("%s", result[1])
      end
      print(string.format("[%s] = %s,", field, result))
    end
    print("}}")
  end
  -- print(string.format("languagesystem %s %s;", script, language))
  print("\\directlua{")
  print_feature("liga", "liga", "ligature", "replaces", "lookups")
  print_feature("ccmp", "ccmp", "multiple", "lookups", "replaces")
  print_feature("gsub", "gsub", "substitution","lookups", "replaces")
  print "}"
end

args = lapp [[
maptolua.lua Convert teckit map files to Luaotfload feature tables
Usage:
texlua maptolua.lua [options] <map file> [glyph list file]
-l,--language  (default dflt) language name in OpenType format
-s,--script  (default LATN) script name in OpenType format
-b,--back  create back mapping
<map_file> (string) file to be converted
[glyph_list] (defualt glyphlist.txt) file in Adobe glyh list format with unicode to glyph names mapping
]]

-- if not arg[1] then
--   print "Usage:"
--   print "texlua maptofea.lua mapfile [glyph list] > featurefile.fea"
--   os.exit()
-- end

-- map files use Unicode values, we need to transform them to the glyph names
-- table with glyph list can be either passes as second argument, or one shipped in TL is used
local glyphfile = args.glyph_list or kpse.find_file("glyphlist.txt", "map")

local glyphtable = load_glyph_list(glyphfile)

-- load the map file, search for unicode values and replace them with glyph names
local maptable = load_map_file(args.map_file, glyphtable)

print_fea_file(args.script, args.language, maptable)
```

It can be executed like:

```
texlua maptolua.lua  cyr.map  > newfeat.tex
```

Which produces a following TeX file:

```
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name='liga',
    type='ligature',
    data={
["–"] = {"-","-"},
["—"] = {"-","-","-"},
["”"] = {"'","'"},
["“"] = {"`","`"},
["¡"] = {"!","`"},
["¿"] = {"?","`"},
["„"] = {",",","},
["«"] = {"<","<"},
["»"] = {">",">"},
}}
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name='ccmp',
    type='multiple',
    data={
["Ю"] = {"J","u"},
["Я"] = {"J","a"},
["ю"] = {"j","u"},
["я"] = {"j","a"},
["є"] = {"j","e"},
["Ѩ"] = {"J","e"},
["Щ"] = {"Š","Č"},
["щ"] = {"š","č"},
}}
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name='gsub',
    type='substitution',
    data={
["'"] = "’",
["`"] = "‘",
["А"] = "A",
["Б"] = "B",
["В"] = "V",
["Г"] = "G",
["Д"] = "D",
["Е"] = "E",
["Ж"] = "Ž",
["З"] = "Z",
["И"] = "J",
["К"] = "K",
["Л"] = "L",
["М"] = "M",
["Н"] = "N",
["О"] = "O",
["П"] = "P",
["Р"] = "R",
["С"] = "S",
["Т"] = "T",
["У"] = "U",
["Ф"] = "F",
["Ц"] = "C",
["Ч"] = "Č",
["Ш"] = "Š",
["Э"] = "Ė",
["Ё"] = "Ë",
["а"] = "a",
["б"] = "b",
["в"] = "v",
["г"] = "g",
["д"] = "d",
["е"] = "e",
["ж"] = "ž",
["з"] = "z",
["и"] = "i",
["й"] = "j",
["к"] = "k",
["л"] = "l",
["м"] = "m",
["н"] = "n",
["о"] = "o",
["п"] = "p",
["р"] = "r",
["с"] = "s",
["т"] = "t",
["у"] = "u",
["ф"] = "f",
["ц"] = "c",
["ч"] = "č",
["ш"] = "š",
["э"] = "ė",
["ё"] = "ë",
["і"] = "i",
["І"] = "I",
["Х"] = "X",
["х"] = "x",
["И"] = "I",
["Ъ"] = "'",
["Ы"] = "Y",
["Ь"] = "’",
["ъ"] = "’",
["ы"] = "y",
["ь"] = "’",
}}
}
```

It can be used in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\input{newfeat.tex}
\setmainfont[RawFeature=+gsub;]{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{document}
\ifxetex
This is XeTeX
\else\ifluatex
This is LuaTeX
\fi\fi


Hello,, -- --- world я щ 
Здравствуй, Мир

\end{document}
```

(Note that it is necessary to use `RawFeature=+gsub;` in the font declaration)

And this is the result:

[image]

---

@edit added support for replacing one glyph with multiple new ones

LuaTeX doesn't support mapping files, but on the other hand it supports [OpenType feature files](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html). There is a major difference between the two, the first one works on character level and with unicode values, the other with glyph names.

I've created simple script for converting the map files to `.fea` files, `maptofea.lua`:

```lua
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"
local lapp = require "lapp-mk4"

local function load_glyph_list(filename)
  local t = {}
  for line in io.lines(filename) do
    local glyph, code = line:match("([^;]+);([A-Fa-f0-9]+)")
    if glyph then
      code = string.upper(code)
      -- print(code, glyph)
      t[code] = glyph
    end
  end
  return t
end

local function load_map_file(mapfile, glyph_list)
  local glyph_list = glyph_list or {}
  local parse_codepoints = function(s)
    local t = {}
    local s = string.upper(s)
    for x in s:gmatch("U%+([0-9A-F]+)") do
      t[#t+1] = glyph_list[x] or "undefined"
    end
    return t
  end
  local t = {liga = {}, gsub = {}, ccmp= {}}
  for line in io.lines(mapfile) do
    -- search for 
    local lookup, replace = line:match("([^%<]+)<>([^%;]+)")
    -- process lines which define mappings
    if lookup then
      -- convert strings with unicode codepoints to tables with glyph names
      local lookups = parse_codepoints(lookup)
      local replaces = parse_codepoints(replace)
      -- print(table.concat(lookups, ";"), "+", table.concat(replaces, ";"))
      local newt = {lookups = lookups, replaces = replaces}
      if #lookups > 1 then
        table.insert(t.liga, newt)
      elseif #replaces > 1 then
        table.insert(t.ccmp, newt)
      else 
        table.insert(t.gsub, newt)
      end
    end
  end
  return t
end

local function print_fea_file(script, language,  maptable)
  local function print_feature(feature) 
    print("feature " .. feature .. " {")
    for _, entry in ipairs(maptable[feature]) do
      print(string.format("  sub %s by %s;", table.concat(entry.lookups, " "), table.concat(entry.replaces, " ")))
    end
    print("} ".. feature .. ";")
  end
  print(string.format("languagesystem %s %s;", script, language))
  print_feature "liga"
  print_feature "ccmp"
  print_feature "gsub"
end

local args = lapp [[
maptofea.lua Convert teckit map files to OpenType feature files
Usage:
texlua maptofea.lua [options] <map file> [glyph list file]
-l,--language  (default dflt) language name in OpenType format
-s,--script  (default LATN) script name in OpenType format
<map_file> (string) file to be converted
[glyph_list] (defualt glyphlist.txt) file in Adobe glyh list format with unicode to glyph names mapping
]]

-- if not arg[1] then
--   print "Usage:"
--   print "texlua maptofea.lua mapfile [glyph list] > featurefile.fea"
--   os.exit()
-- end

-- map files use Unicode values, we need to transform them to the glyph names
-- table with glyph list can be either passes as second argument, or one shipped in TL is used
local glyphfile = arg[2] or kpse.find_file("glyphlist.txt", "map")

local glyphtable = load_glyph_list(glyphfile)

-- load the map file, search for unicode values and replace them with glyph names
local maptable = load_map_file(arg[1], glyphtable)

print_fea_file(args.script, args.language, maptable)
```

It's help message:

```
maptofea.lua Convert teckit map files to OpenType feature files
Usage:
texlua maptofea.lua [options] <map file> [glyph list file]
-l,--language  (default dflt) language name in OpenType format
-s,--script  (default LATN) script name in OpenType format
<map_file> (string) file to be converted
[glyph_list] (defualt glyphlist.txt) file in Adobe glyh list format with unicode to glyph names mapping
```

you can just simply use it without any options on a map file:

```
texlua maptofea.lua cyrillic-to-latin.map > cyrtolatn2.fea
```

the converted file `cyrtolatn2.fea`:

```
languagesystem LATN dflt;
feature liga {
  sub hyphen hyphen by endash;
  sub hyphen hyphen hyphen by emdash;
  sub quotesingle quotesingle by quotedblright;
  sub grave grave by quotedblleft;
  sub exclam grave by exclamdown;
  sub question grave by questiondown;
  sub comma comma by quotedblbase;
  sub less less by guillemotleft;
  sub greater greater by guillemotright;
} liga;
feature ccmp {
  sub afii10048 by J u;
  sub afii10049 by J a;
  sub iucyrillic by j u;
  sub iacyrillic by j a;
  sub ecyrillic by j e;
  sub Yuslittleiotifiedcyrillic by J e;
  sub afii10043 by Scaron Ccaron;
  sub shchacyrillic by scaron ccaron;
} ccmp;
feature gsub {
  sub quotesingle by quoteright;
  sub grave by quoteleft;
  sub afii10017 by A;
  sub afii10018 by B;
  sub afii10019 by V;
  sub afii10020 by G;
  sub afii10021 by D;
  sub afii10022 by E;
  sub afii10024 by Zcaron;
  sub afii10025 by Z;
  sub afii10026 by J;
  sub afii10028 by K;
  sub afii10029 by L;
  sub afii10030 by M;
  sub afii10031 by N;
  sub afii10032 by O;
  sub afii10033 by P;
  sub afii10034 by R;
  sub afii10035 by S;
  sub afii10036 by T;
  sub afii10037 by U;
  sub afii10038 by F;
  sub afii10040 by C;
  sub afii10041 by Ccaron;
  sub afii10042 by Scaron;
  sub afii10047 by Edotaccent;
  sub afii10023 by Edieresis;
  sub afii10065 by a;
  sub becyrillic by b;
  sub vecyrillic by v;
  sub gecyrillic by g;
  sub decyrillic by d;
  sub iecyrillic by e;
  sub zhecyrillic by zcaron;
  sub zecyrillic by z;
  sub iicyrillic by i;
  sub iishortcyrillic by j;
  sub kacyrillic by k;
  sub elcyrillic by l;
  sub emcyrillic by m;
  sub encyrillic by n;
  sub ocyrillic by o;
  sub pecyrillic by p;
  sub ercyrillic by r;
  sub escyrillic by s;
  sub tecyrillic by t;
  sub ucyrillic by u;
  sub efcyrillic by f;
  sub tsecyrillic by c;
  sub checyrillic by ccaron;
  sub shacyrillic by scaron;
  sub ereversedcyrillic by edotaccent;
  sub iocyrillic by edieresis;
  sub icyrillic by i;
  sub afii10055 by I;
  sub afii10039 by X;
  sub khacyrillic by x;
  sub afii10026 by I;
  sub afii10044 by quotesingle;
  sub afii10045 by Y;
  sub afii10046 by quoteright;
  sub hardsigncyrillic by quoteright;
  sub yericyrillic by y;
  sub softsigncyrillic by quoteright;
} gsub;
```

You have to request the feature file and also `gsub` opentype feature in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

\setmainfont[Mapping=cyrillic-to-latin,FeatureFile=cyrtolatn2.fea, RawFeature={+gsub;+liga;}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\ifxetex
    This is XeTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is LuaTeX
\fi\fi

Hello,, -- ---  world я щ 
Здравствуй, Мир

\end{document}
```

and this is the result:
[image: ]]

**Upgrade for the 2016 TeXLive distribution.**

The new release does not support the inclusion of a .fea file, making obsolete this method. A workaround can be made by the use of `\directlua` as follows:

```
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "myliga",
         type = "ligature",
         data = {
             ['Aacute'] = { "А", 0x0301},
             ['Eacute'] = { "Е", 0x0301},
             ['Iacute'] = { "И", 0x0301},
             ['iacute'] = { "и", 0x0301},
             ['Oacute'] = { "О", 0x0301},
             ['Uacute'] = { "У", 0x0301},
             ['Yacute'] = { "Ы", 0x0301},         
             ['Egrave'] = { "Э", 0x0301},         
             ['egrave'] = { "э", 0x0301},         
        },
    }
}

\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "mycomp",
         type = "multiple",
         data = {
             afii10039 = { "C", "h" },
             afii10087 = { "c", "h" },
             afii10048 = { "J", "u" },
             afii10049 = { "J", "a" },
             afii10096 = { "j", "u" },
             afii10097 = { "j", "a" },
             Yuslittleiotifiedcyrillic = { "J", "e" },
             afii10043 = { "Scaron", "ccaron" },
             afii10091 = { "scaron", "ccaron" },
        },
    }
}

\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "mysub",
            type = "substitution",
            data = {
                ["quotesingle"] = "quoteright",
                ["grave"] = "quoteleft",
                ["afii10017"] = "A",
                ["afii10018"] = "B",
                ["afii10019"] = "V",
                ["afii10020"] = "G",
                ["afii10021"] = "D",
                ["afii10022"] = "E",
                ["afii10024"] = "Zcaron",
                ["afii10025"] = "Z",
                ["afii10026"] = "I",
                ["afii10027"] = "J",
                ["afii10028"] = "K",
                ["afii10029"] = "L",
                ["afii10030"] = "M",
                ["afii10031"] = "N",
                ["afii10032"] = "O",
                ["afii10033"] = "P",
                ["afii10034"] = "R",
                ["afii10035"] = "S",
                ["afii10036"] = "T",
                ["afii10037"] = "U",
                ["afii10038"] = "F",
                ["afii10040"] = "C",
                ["afii10041"] = "Ccaron",
                ["afii10042"] = "Scaron",
                ["afii10047"] = "Edotaccent",
                ["afii10023"] = "Edieresis",
                ["afii10065"] = "a",
                ["afii10066"] = "b",
                ["afii10067"] = "v",
                ["afii10068"] = "g",
                ["afii10069"] = "d",
                ["afii10070"] = "e",
                ["afii10072"] = "zcaron",
                ["afii10073"] = "z",
                ["afii10074"] = "i",
                ["afii10075"] = "j",
                ["afii10076"] = "k",
                ["afii10077"] = "l",
                ["afii10078"] = "m",
                ["afii10079"] = "n",
                ["afii10080"] = "o",
                ["afii10081"] = "p",
                ["afii10082"] = "r",
                ["afii10083"] = "s",
                ["afii10084"] = "t",
                ["afii10085"] = "u",
                ["afii10086"] = "f",
                ["afii10088"] = "c",
                ["afii10089"] = "ccaron",
                ["afii10090"] = "scaron",
                ["afii10095"] = "edotaccent",
                ["afii10071"] = "edieresis",
                ["afii10103"] = "i",
                ["afii10055"] = "I",
                ["afii10026"] = "I",
                ["afii10044"] = "quoteright",
                ["afii10045"] = "Y",
                ["afii10046"] = "quoteright",
                ["afii10092"] = "quoteright",
                ["afii10093"] = "y",
                ["afii10094"] = "quoteright",
        },
    }
}
```

The features defined above must be called in the usual way.

```
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[RawFeature={+mysub;+mycomp;+myliga}]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Michal.h21. I copied directly the .fea file you generated and works perfectly. But if I try to generate it with the maptofea.lua file with the procedure you edited I generate a cyrtofean2.fea file with just this lines:

`maptofea.lua:2: module 'lapp-mk4' not found:`
 `no field package.preload['lapp-mk4']`
 `[kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'lapp-mk4'`
 `[kpse C searcher] file not found: 'lapp-mk4'`

Comment: @PaoloPolesana do you have recent TeX Live? It should be included since TeX Live 2014. Anyway, you can find that file [here](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/blob/master/lapp-mk4.lua)

Comment: Yes, @Michal.h21, I have TeX Live 2015. Anyway, what should I do with the file lapp-mk4.lua? Do I have to save it in a particular place? This is the first time I approach to .lua files... Tanks!

Comment: it is strange, it should work for you then. anyway, you should put it along with `maptofea.lua`

Comment: Excuse me, @Michal.h21, but I found a bug in your method, which is actually very good because it keeps the thing on the font feature side. The bug occurs with, at least, the letters 'щ' 'ю' 'я', since they are replaced with a couple of latin letters 'šč', 'ju' and 'ja'. 

I actually modified the transliteration rules in cyrillic-to-latin.map to mach italian transliteration rules and the problem occurs also with 'х', which should turn to 'ch'.

Comment: @PaoloPolesana where can I find your modified map file?

Comment: You can find the file above in DavidCarlisle Answer. Anyway it is common in all cyrillic transliteration rules to use couples of letters, as it already was in the previous system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33869/discussion-between-paolo-polesana-and-michal-h21).

Comment: Excuse me, @michal.h21, I installed the new 2016 and this distribution does not allows the transliteration method you suggested [while continues working with the 2015 edtion]. Do you have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @PaoloPolesana it seems that support for feature files was removed from the current LuaTeX :( I think some new mechanism is available, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I think it deserves some discussion in the community: wouldn't it be better to post this as a new question?

Comment: @PaoloPolesana probably yes, `luaotfload` people will know better about it and they more likely to read it in separate question

Comment: Dear Michal, I have found the way to upgrade the method with the help of \directlua, which is able to define font features as explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312154/how-to-adjust-font-features-in-luatex. Actually this answer became obsolete: do you think it is wort to upgrade it? I prepared the patch.

Comment: @PaoloPolesana sure, please post the patch here :)

Comment: I have used your \directlua workaround to transliterate other scripts. It works great, but I was wondering whether it is possible to transliterate multiple characters into one. E.g., how would one include a line that gets Cyrillic щ from Latin šč and я from ya? (There will be conflicts when one tries to convert both šč and š and č, but it is easier to work around those conflicts then to be delimited by using only one character.)

Comment: @Jopie add line `['щ'] = {"š", "č"},` to the `myliga` part. also note that the code in this answer doesn'ŧ work anymore, `name`, `type` and `data` should be on the same level

Answer (score 13):

[image]

this was typeset with luatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

\setmainfont[Mapping=cyrillic-to-latin]{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\ifxetex
    This is XeTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is LuaTeX

\directlua{require("cyrtr")}

\fi

Hello, world

Здравствуй, Мир

\end{document}
```

using a cyrtr.lua more or less generated from the mapping file in the linked question. (I messed up a bit on some of the quote characters, you'll need to add them back)

```
function cyrtr (s)
return
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
s,
'А','A'),
'Б','B'),
'В','V'),
'Г','G'),
'Д','D'),
'Е','E'),
'Ж','Ž'),
'З','Z'),
'И','I'),
'К','K'),
'Л','L'),
'М','M'),
'Н','N'),
'О','O'),
'П','P'),
'Р','R'),
'С','S'),
'Т','T'),
'У','U'),
'Ф','F'),
'Ц','C'),
'Ч','Č'),
'Ш','Š'),
'Э','Ė'),
'Ю','Ju'),
'Я','Ja'),
'Ё','Ë'),
'а','a'),
'б','b'),
'в','v'),
'г','g'),
'д','d'),
'е','e'),
'ж','ž'),
'з','z'),
'и','i'),
'й','j'),
'к','k'),
'л','l'),
'м','m'),
'н','n'),
'о','o'),
'п','p'),
'р','r'),
'с','s'),
'т','t'),
'у','u'),
'ф','f'),
'ц','c'),
'ч','č'),
'ш','š'),
'э','ė'),
'ю','ju'),
'я','ja'),
'ё','ë'),
'і','i'),
'І','I'),
'є','je'),
'Ѩ','Je'),
'Х','X'),
'х','x'),
'И','I'),
'Щ','Šč'),
'Ы','Y'),
'щ','šč'),
'ы','y')
end


luatexbase.add_to_callback(
"process_input_buffer",
cyrtr,
"cyrillic transliteration")
```

Anyway, this transliteration is one of the possible. Different language have different transliteration systems.

Comment: Excuse me, @DavidCarlisle, it seems there is some formatting problem and I'm not sure I correctly understood. The command for each letter is string.gsub('А','A'), etc..., isn't it? The last should be string.gsub('ы','y') followed by 's' character. Am I right?

Comment: @PaoloPolesana No the file is should be as shown, did you try it? The first replacement is not A A it is U+0410 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A 
U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A    even though they both look like A above. `s` just appears once at the start of the chain of replacements.

Comment: Beautiful! It works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Excuse me, @DavidCarlisle, I changed your cyrtr file with cyrtr2 file fixing the translitteration 'И','J' to 'И','I', which is correct. Anyway, I'm discussing some problems risen with your method in this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286071/fixing-problems-in-latin-translitteration-of-acute-accented-cyrillic-vowels-with

Comment: @PaoloPolesana thanks you may edit the answer above if you wish so later readers are not confused (as I can't read the script there is a big chance I make it worse if I edit it:-)

Answer (score 3):

Extending the answer space a little:

With **expl3**, there is a slightly more portable (non-lua) solution: the `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` function is available, of the form:

```
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { д } { d }
```

It is fast and easy to use. This is one case where expl3 regex is too powerful.

Proof of concept for the Cyrillic Unicode codeblock: sample of half a dozen Cyrillic-using languages (Komi, Ingush, Udmurt, etc), with transliteration per GOST 7.79-2000, ISO9:1995 standard.

[image: Example translation]

It is already apparent  that Latin lookalike letters (such as Æ, I, X) are becoming mixed-up with their Cyrillic counterparts (Ӕ, Ӏ, Х), at least in Wikipedia. The codepoints are completely different.

The lookup code is basically copy-paste from a spreadsheet which uses `concatenate` function to build up the codestring, so is easy to maintain. The to-from table feeding the concatenate is another copy-paste (from Wikipedia, so will need proofing).

**Update**

For the replacement function, combining diacritical marks count as characters in a string, so longest strings should be replaced before shorter ones to get the correct transliteration. Code in MWE has been updated.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Colour=red]
\newfontfamily\fcyrtrans{Noto Serif}%[Colour=blue]
\newfontfamily\forig{Noto Serif}


\ExplSyntaxOn


%-----   transliteration
\tl_new:N \l_mycy_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \cyrtrans } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_mycy_tl { #1 }
 \docyrtrans 
 \tl_use:N \l_mycy_tl
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{cyrtranse}{ +b } 
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_mycy_tl { #1 }
\docyrtrans 
{ \tl_use:N \l_mycy_tl }
}
{ }


\newcommand\docyrtrans{%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { о̄̈ } { { \fcyrtrans ọ̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӓ̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ạ̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { А̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ā}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { А́ } { { \fcyrtrans Á}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { А̊ } { { \fcyrtrans Å}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { И́ } { { \fcyrtrans Í}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { І̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ǐ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ј̵ } { { \fcyrtrans J́}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { К̨ } { { \fcyrtrans K̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Н̄ } { { \fcyrtrans N̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӧ̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ọ̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { О́ } { { \fcyrtrans Ó}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { О̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ō}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { С̀ } { { \fcyrtrans S̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Т̌ } { { \fcyrtrans Ť}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { У́ } { { \fcyrtrans Ú}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӱ̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ụ̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ч̀ } { { \fcyrtrans C̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ы̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ȳ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ю̄ } { { \fcyrtrans Û̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӓ̄ } { { \fcyrtrans ạ̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { а̄ } { { \fcyrtrans ā}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { а́ } { { \fcyrtrans á}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { а̊ } { { \fcyrtrans å}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { и́ } { { \fcyrtrans í}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { і̄ } { { \fcyrtrans ǐ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ј̵ } { { \fcyrtrans j́}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { к̨ } { { \fcyrtrans k̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { н̄ } { { \fcyrtrans n̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { о́ } { { \fcyrtrans ó}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { о̄ } { { \fcyrtrans ō}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { с̀ } { { \fcyrtrans s̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { т̌ } { { \fcyrtrans ť}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { у́ } { { \fcyrtrans ú}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӱ̄ } { { \fcyrtrans ụ̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ч̀ } { { \fcyrtrans c̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ы̄ } { { \fcyrtrans ȳ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ю̄ } { { \fcyrtrans û̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { А } { { \fcyrtrans A}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӓ } { { \fcyrtrans Ä}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӑ } { { \fcyrtrans Ă}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӕ } { { \fcyrtrans Æ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Б } { { \fcyrtrans B}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { В } { { \fcyrtrans V}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Г } { { \fcyrtrans G}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ѓ } { { \fcyrtrans Ǵ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ғ } { { \fcyrtrans Ġ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҕ } { { \fcyrtrans Ğ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Һ } { { \fcyrtrans Ḥ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Д } { { \fcyrtrans D}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ђ } { { \fcyrtrans Đ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Е } { { \fcyrtrans E}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӗ } { { \fcyrtrans Ĕ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ё } { { \fcyrtrans Ë}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Є } { { \fcyrtrans Ê}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ж } { { \fcyrtrans Ž}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Җ } { { \fcyrtrans Ž̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӝ } { { \fcyrtrans Z̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӂ } { { \fcyrtrans Z̆}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { З } { { \fcyrtrans Z}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӟ } { { \fcyrtrans Z̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӡ } { { \fcyrtrans Ź}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ѕ } { { \fcyrtrans Ẑ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { И } { { \fcyrtrans I}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӣ } { { \fcyrtrans Ī}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӥ } { { \fcyrtrans Î}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Й } { { \fcyrtrans J}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { І } { { \fcyrtrans Ì}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ї } { { \fcyrtrans Ï}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ј } { { \fcyrtrans J̌}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { К } { { \fcyrtrans K}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ќ } { { \fcyrtrans Ḱ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӄ } { { \fcyrtrans Ḳ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҝ } { { \fcyrtrans K̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҡ } { { \fcyrtrans Ǩ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҟ } { { \fcyrtrans K̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Қ } { { \fcyrtrans K̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԛ } { { \fcyrtrans Q}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Л } { { \fcyrtrans L}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Љ } { { \fcyrtrans L̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԡ } { { \fcyrtrans L̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { М } { { \fcyrtrans M}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Н } { { \fcyrtrans N}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Њ } { { \fcyrtrans N̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ң } { { \fcyrtrans N̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӊ } { { \fcyrtrans Ṇ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҥ } { { \fcyrtrans Ṅ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԋ } { { \fcyrtrans Ǹ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԣ } { { \fcyrtrans Ń}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӈ } { { \fcyrtrans Ň}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { О } { { \fcyrtrans O}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӧ } { { \fcyrtrans Ö}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ө } { { \fcyrtrans Ô}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӫ } { { \fcyrtrans Ő}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҩ } { { \fcyrtrans Ò}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Œ } { { \fcyrtrans Œ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { П } { { \fcyrtrans P}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҧ } { { \fcyrtrans Ṕ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԥ } { { \fcyrtrans P̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Р } { { \fcyrtrans R}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { С } { { \fcyrtrans S}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҫ } { { \fcyrtrans Ș}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Т } { { \fcyrtrans T}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ћ } { { \fcyrtrans Ć}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԏ } { { \fcyrtrans T̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҭ } { { \fcyrtrans Ț}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { У } { { \fcyrtrans U}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӱ } { { \fcyrtrans Ü}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӯ } { { \fcyrtrans Ū}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ў } { { \fcyrtrans Ŭ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӳ } { { \fcyrtrans Ű}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ү } { { \fcyrtrans Ù}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ұ } { { \fcyrtrans U̇}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ԝ } { { \fcyrtrans W}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ф } { { \fcyrtrans F}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Х } { { \fcyrtrans H}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҳ } { { \fcyrtrans H̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ц } { { \fcyrtrans C}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҵ } { { \fcyrtrans C̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Џ } { { \fcyrtrans D̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ч } { { \fcyrtrans Č}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҷ } { { \fcyrtrans C̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӌ } { { \fcyrtrans C̣}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӵ } { { \fcyrtrans C̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҹ } { { \fcyrtrans Ĉ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҽ } { { \fcyrtrans C̆}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ҿ } { { \fcyrtrans C̨̆}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ш } { { \fcyrtrans Š}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Щ } { { \fcyrtrans Ŝ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ъ } { { \fcyrtrans ʺ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ы } { { \fcyrtrans Y}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӹ } { { \fcyrtrans Ÿ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ь } { { \fcyrtrans ʹ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Э } { { \fcyrtrans È}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ә } { { \fcyrtrans A̋}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӛ } { { \fcyrtrans À}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ю } { { \fcyrtrans Û}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Я } { { \fcyrtrans Â}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ґ } { { \fcyrtrans G̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ѣ } { { \fcyrtrans Ě}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ѫ } { { \fcyrtrans Ǎ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ѳ } { { \fcyrtrans F̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ѵ } { { \fcyrtrans Ỳ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Ӏ } { { \fcyrtrans ‡}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ʼ } { { \fcyrtrans ʼ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ˮ } { { \fcyrtrans ˮ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { а } { { \fcyrtrans a}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӓ } { { \fcyrtrans ä}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӑ } { { \fcyrtrans ă}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӕ } { { \fcyrtrans æ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { б } { { \fcyrtrans b}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { в } { { \fcyrtrans v}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { г } { { \fcyrtrans g}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ѓ } { { \fcyrtrans ǵ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ғ } { { \fcyrtrans ġ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҕ } { { \fcyrtrans ğ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { һ } { { \fcyrtrans ḥ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { д } { { \fcyrtrans d}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ђ } { { \fcyrtrans đ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { е } { { \fcyrtrans e}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӗ } { { \fcyrtrans ĕ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ё } { { \fcyrtrans ë}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { є } { { \fcyrtrans ê}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ж } { { \fcyrtrans ž}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { җ } { { \fcyrtrans ž̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӝ } { { \fcyrtrans z̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӂ } { { \fcyrtrans z̆}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { з } { { \fcyrtrans z}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӟ } { { \fcyrtrans z̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӡ } { { \fcyrtrans ź}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ѕ } { { \fcyrtrans ẑ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { и } { { \fcyrtrans i}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӣ } { { \fcyrtrans ī}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӥ } { { \fcyrtrans î}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { й } { { \fcyrtrans j}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { і } { { \fcyrtrans ì}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ї } { { \fcyrtrans ï}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ј } { { \fcyrtrans ǰ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { к } { { \fcyrtrans k}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ќ } { { \fcyrtrans ḱ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӄ } { { \fcyrtrans ḳ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҝ } { { \fcyrtrans k̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҡ } { { \fcyrtrans ǩ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҟ } { { \fcyrtrans k̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { қ } { { \fcyrtrans k̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԛ } { { \fcyrtrans q}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { л } { { \fcyrtrans l}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { љ } { { \fcyrtrans l̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԡ } { { \fcyrtrans l̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { м } { { \fcyrtrans m}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { н } { { \fcyrtrans n}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { њ } { { \fcyrtrans n̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ң } { { \fcyrtrans n̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӊ } { { \fcyrtrans ṇ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҥ } { { \fcyrtrans ṅ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԋ } { { \fcyrtrans ǹ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԣ } { { \fcyrtrans ń}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӈ } { { \fcyrtrans ň}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { о } { { \fcyrtrans o}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӧ } { { \fcyrtrans ö}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ө } { { \fcyrtrans ô}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӫ } { { \fcyrtrans ő}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҩ } { { \fcyrtrans ò}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { œ } { { \fcyrtrans œ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { п } { { \fcyrtrans p}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҧ } { { \fcyrtrans ṕ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԥ } { { \fcyrtrans p̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { р } { { \fcyrtrans r}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { с } { { \fcyrtrans s}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҫ } { { \fcyrtrans ș}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { т } { { \fcyrtrans t}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ћ } { { \fcyrtrans ć}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԏ } { { \fcyrtrans t̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҭ } { { \fcyrtrans ț}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { у } { { \fcyrtrans u}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӱ } { { \fcyrtrans ü}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӯ } { { \fcyrtrans ū}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ў } { { \fcyrtrans ŭ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӳ } { { \fcyrtrans ű}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ү } { { \fcyrtrans ù}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ұ } { { \fcyrtrans u̇}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ԝ } { { \fcyrtrans w}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ф } { { \fcyrtrans f}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { х } { { \fcyrtrans h}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҳ } { { \fcyrtrans h̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ц } { { \fcyrtrans c}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҵ } { { \fcyrtrans c̄}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { џ } { { \fcyrtrans d̂}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ч } { { \fcyrtrans č}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҷ } { { \fcyrtrans c̦}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӌ } { { \fcyrtrans c̣}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӵ } { { \fcyrtrans c̈}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҹ } { { \fcyrtrans ĉ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҽ } { { \fcyrtrans c̆}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ҿ } { { \fcyrtrans c̨̆}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ш } { { \fcyrtrans š}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { щ } { { \fcyrtrans ŝ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ъ } { { \fcyrtrans }}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ы } { { \fcyrtrans y}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӹ } { { \fcyrtrans ÿ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ь } { { \fcyrtrans }}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { э } { { \fcyrtrans è}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ә } { { \fcyrtrans a̋}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ӛ } { { \fcyrtrans à}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ю } { { \fcyrtrans û}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { я } { { \fcyrtrans â}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ґ } { { \fcyrtrans g̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ѣ } { { \fcyrtrans ě}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ѫ } { { \fcyrtrans ǎ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ѳ } { { \fcyrtrans f̀}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { ѵ } { { \fcyrtrans ỳ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { X } { { \fcyrtrans X}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { I } { { \fcyrtrans I}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { Æ } { { \fcyrtrans Æ}}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mycy_tl { æ } { { \fcyrtrans æ}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

{\forig Солнечная система -- \bfseries inline transliteration: } 
\cyrtrans{Солнечная система}

{\forig 
Implementing a GOST 7.79-2000, ISO9:1995, transliteration scheme.

Extract is from Wikipedia article on the solar system, in some Cyrillic-using languages: Russian, Ingush, Komi etc. Red is original untransliterated text.
}

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Russian ru русский язык }

\begin{cyrtranse}

Со́лнечная систе́ма — планетная система, включает в себя центральную звезду — Солнце — и все естественные космические объекты, вращающиеся вокруг Солнца. Она сформировалась путём гравитационного сжатия газопылевого облака примерно 4,57 млрд лет назад[2].

Общая масса Солнечной системы составляет около 1,0014 M☉. Бо́льшая часть её приходится на Солнце; оставшаяся часть практически полностью содержится в восьми отдалённых друг от друга планетах, имеющих близкие к круговым орбиты, лежащие почти в одной плоскости — плоскости эклиптики. Из-за этого наблюдается противоречащее ожидаемому распределение момента импульса между Солнцем и планетами (так называемая «проблема моментов»): всего 2 \% общего момента системы приходится на долю Солнца, масса которого в ~740 раз больше общей массы планет, а остальные 98 \% — на \textasciitilde 0,001 общей массы Солнечной системы[18]. 

\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------


%\bigskip
%{\forig \bfseries Environment: ccc}\par
%\begin{cyrtranse}
%\end{cyrtranse}
%%-------------------------------------------------

%\bigskip
%{\forig \bfseries Environment: ccc}\par
%\begin{cyrtranse}
%\end{cyrtranse}
%%-------------------------------------------------



\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Tajik tg тоҷикӣ}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Манзумаи офтобӣ
Системаи офтобӣ

    Офтоб
    Уторид
    Зуҳра
    Замин
    Моҳ
    Миррих
    Муштарӣ
    Сатурн
    Уран
    Нептун

    Серера
    Плутон
    
    Офтоб ё Хуршед (аз оф — ҷирм ва тоб тобанда, тобоӣ), Шамс, Меҳр, Xуршед (астр. ☉) — наздиктарин ситораест, ки дар маркази манзумаи хуршедӣ воқеъ буда, аз плазмаи тафсон таркиб ёфтааст. Аломати астрономиаш Офтоб. Массаи Офтоб 1,990*1030 килограмм буда, аз массаи Замин 332958 маротиба зиёд аст ва 99,866 \% -и массаи ҷирмҳои манзумаи хуршедиро ташкил медиҳад. Масофаи байни Офтоб ва Замни дар давоми сол аз 147,1 миллион километр (январ) то 152,1 миллион километр (июл) тағйир меёбад. Қимати миёнааш 149,6 миллион километр аст, ки онро чун воҳиди астрономӣ қабул кардаанд. Зичии миёнаи моддаи Офтоб 1,41-10® килограмм/метрэ. Тезшавии қувваи вазнинӣ дар сатҳи Офтоб 273,98 м/ооп2. Ҳарорати сатди Офтоб, ки аз рӯи афканиши пурраи он мувофиқи қонуни афканишоти Стефану Болс­ман муайян карда мешавад, ба 57ТО К баробар аст.

Баъд аз ихтирои телескоп мушоҳидаи Офтоб характери илмӣ пайдо кард. Доғҳои Офтоб кашф ва даври чархзании он дар атрофи меҳвараш муайян карда шуд. Соли 1843 астрономи немис Г. Швабе даврияти хурӯҷи Офтобро ошкор кард. Соли 1814 Й. Фра­унгофер дар спектри Офтоб хатҳои тираи фурӯбурдро дарёфт. Аз соли 1836 ин ҷониб гирифти Офтобро мунтазам мушоҳида мекунанд. Дар натиҷа дар Офтоб тоҷ, хромосфера, инчунин протӯберансҳо ошкор гарди­данд. Соли 1913 астрономи америкоӣ Ҷ. Ҳенл спектри доғдои Офтобро омӯхта дар Офтоб мавҷуд будани майдони магнитиро исбот кард. Дар ибтидои солҳои 40 садаи XX радиоафканишоти Офтобро кашф карданд. Дар нимаи дуюми садаи XX инкишофи гидродинамика ва физикаи плазма боиси пешравии физикаи Офтоб шуд. Ҳоло бо ёрии мушакҳо, расадхонаҳои автоматии маҳорӣ, лабораторияҳои кайҳонии пилотдор афканишоти ултрабунафш ва рентгении Офтобро тадқиқ мекунанд.
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Komi kv Коми кыв}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Шонді ылдӧс
Перейти к навигации
Перейти к поиску

Шонді ылдӧс (рочӧн Солнечная система) — планетаяслӧн система, кытчӧ пырӧны медшӧр кодзув — Шонді — да сы гӧгӧр бергалысь космос объектъяс. Сійӧ артмис кӧнкӧ 4,57 миллиард во сайын бус да ру сора кымӧрлӧн гравитационнӧй коллапс отсӧгӧн.

Шонді.

Планет: Меркурий, Венера, Му, Марс, Юпитер, Сатурн, Уран, Нептун.

Карлик планета: Плутон, Церера, Эрида, Макемаке, Хаумеа.

Тӧлысь. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Ossetian os Ирон æвзаг}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Хуры системæ
Сæрибар энциклопеди Википедийы æрмæг.
Перейти к навигации
Перейти к поиску
Хуры системæйы планетæтæ

Хуры системæ[1] у планетæты системæ галактикæ Æрфæныфæды. 

Æрфæныфæд
Сæрибар энциклопеди Википедийы æрмæг.
Перейти к навигации
Перейти к поиску
Æрфæныфæд (компьютерон ныв)

Æрфæныфæд (гр. {\forig Γαλαξίας}, лат. {\forig Via Lactea}, уырыс. Млечный Путь) у дун-дунейы галактикæтæй иу. Æрфæныфæды ис Хуры системæ.

Æндæр варианттæ сты — чыс.ныхас. Саг æмæ галы фæд[1]; дыгурон диалект Дон.[2]
Ирон мифологийы
Æрфæн-æрвон — Нарты кадджытæм æрвон бæхты мыггагæй, уыд Нарты хистæр Уырызмæджы æмбисонды бæхы ном. Уый хонынц зæххон бæхты фыдæл, уымæй, дам, равзæрдысты. Ирд æхсæвы арвы астæу иу кæронæй иннæмæ цы урсбын фæтæн тæлм фæзыны, уый дæр уымæ гæсгæ ирон адæм хонынц «Æрфæны фæд». 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Ingush inh ГӀалгӀай мотт}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Маьлха ков
Перейти к навигации
Перейти к поиску
Маьлха ковна дуненаш

Маьлха ков (лат: {\forig Systema solare}, эрс: Со́лнечная систе́ма, ингал: {\forig Solar system}) — дунений ража я шийна чулоацаш юкъера седкъа — Малх а — цун гоннахьа кхесташ йола шоаш хьахинна айлама объекташ а. Маьлха ков хьахиннад газ-дема хьисапе морхах гравитационни вIашкатаIар хинна 4,57 млрд шу хьалха[1]. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Bulgarian bg български език}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Слънчевата система е група астрономически обекти, включваща Слънцето и небесните тела, обикалящи около него – планети, планети-джуджета, спътници, астероиди, комети, междупланетен прах и газ. Всички те са образувани при разпадането на молекулярен облак преди около 4,6 милиарда години.

Най-масивни след Слънцето са осемте планети. Техните орбити са почти кръгови и лежат приблизително в една равнина – равнината на еклиптиката. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Belarusian be Беларуская мова}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Сонечная сістэма — зорная сістэма, якая складаецца з Сонца і яго планетнай сістэмы, і якая ўключае ў сябе ўсе натуральныя касмічныя аб'екты, якія абарочваюцца вакол Сонца: планеты і іх спадарожнікі, а таксама малыя целы — астэроіды, метэароіды, каметы, касмічны пыл.

У Сонцы сканцэнтравана пераважная частка ўсёй масы сістэмы (каля 99,866 \%), яно ўтрымлівае сваім прыцягненнем планеты і іншыя целы, якія належаць да Сонечнай сістэмы. Чатыры найбуйнейшыя аб'екты — газавыя гіганты — складаюць 99 \% астатняй масы (пры гэтым большая частка прыпадае на Юпітэр і Сатурн — каля 90 \%). 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Karachay-Balkar krc Къарачай-Малкъар тил}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Кюн система
Перейти к навигации
Перейти к поиску
Кюн система (масштабы сакъланмагъанды)

Кюн низам — орта джулдузу Кюнден эмда аны тёгерегинде бурулгъан табигъат алам объектледен къуралгъан планета низамды.

Ауетлик себебли Кюн бла байламлы болгъан объектлени ауурлугъуну кёбюсю, шартха кёре энчи тургъан, хазна къалмай тёгерек чорхлары болгъан, эмда хазна къалмай джассы дискни — эклиптиканы джассылыгъыны ичинде тургъан планеталадады.

Тёрт гитчерек ич планетала: Атархан, Тандыса, Джер эмда Мырых, джер къауумну планеталары деген ат бла да белиги болгъанла, кёбюсюне силикатла бла темирден къураладыла. Тёрт тыш планетала: Юпитер, Сатурн, Уран эмда Нептун, газ гигантла деген ат бла да белгили болгъанла, иги кесегине водород бла гелийден къураладыла эмда джер къауумну планеталарындан эсе уллу эм ауурладыла.

Кюн низамда гитче затладан толуб тургъан эки бёлге барды. Мырых бла Юпитерни арасында болгъан астероидлени бели, силикатла бла темирледен къуралгъаны себели къурамына кёре джер къауумну планеталарына ушайды. Астероидлени белини эм уллу объектлери Церера, Паллада эм Юнонады. Нептунну орбитасыны артында бузлагъан суудан, аммиакдан эмда метандан къуралгъан транснептун объектле орналыбдыла, аланы эм уллулары Плутон, Седна, Хаумеа, Макемаке эмда Эридады. Бу эки бёлгеде мингле бла гитче затлагъа къошакъгъа башха тюрлю гитче затла да, сёз ючюн, къуйрукълу джулдузла, учхан джулдузла эмда алам букъу, Кюн низамны ичинде айланадыла.

Планеталаны сегизинден алтысы эмда юч шылаб планета, табигъат дженгерле бла къуршаланыбдыла. Тыш планеталаны хар бириси да букъу бла башха миндеуледен тогъайла бла къуршаланыбдыла.

Кюн низам, Къой Джол мырытны къурамына киреди. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Lezghian lez Лезги чӏал}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Ракъинин систе́ма — юкьван гъед тир Рагъ ва Ракъинилай элкъвезвай вири тӀебиатдин космосдин объектар кьазвай планетдин система я. Рагъ галаз гравитациядалди алакъа авай объектрин массадин чӀехи пай муьжуьд нисби тир хелветда гьахьнавай ва саки элкъвей цӀарцӀин орбитаяр авай планетрин къене ава; и планетаяр саки кьулу дискдин сергьятра — эклиптикадин кьулувиле ава:

Кьуд мадни гъвечӀи къенепатан планетаяр: Меркурий, Венера, Ччилни Марс (ибуруз гьакӀни Ччилин кӀеретӀдин планетаярни лугьуда) асул гьисабдалди силикатрикайни металликай ибарат жезва. Кьуд къецепатан планетаяр: Юпитер, Сатурн, Уран ва Нептун (ибуруз гьакӀни газдин гигантарни лугьуда) асул гьисабдалди гьидрогендикайни гьелийдикай ибарат жезва ва Ччилин кӀеретӀдин планетайрилай массив я.

Ракъинин системада гъвечӀи телойрив ацӀурнавай кьве област ава. Марсни Юпитердин арада авай Астероидрин чIул квай затӀариз килигна Ччилин кӀеретӀдин планетаяр галаз сад я, вучиз лагьайтӀа, силикатрикайни металликай ибарат я. Астероидрин чӀулдин виридалайни чӀехи объектар Церера, Паллада ва Веста я. Нептундин орбиталай анихъ муркӀади кьунвай цикай, аммиакдикайни метандикай ибарат тир транснептундин объектар ава, ва и объектрикай виридалайни чӀехи Плутон, Седна, Хаумеа, Макемаке ва Эрида я. И кьве областда агъзурралди гъвечӀи телойриз алава яз, инал гъвечӀи телойрин жуьреба-жуьре популяцияр ава — астероидар, планетрин квазиспутникарни троянар, ччилин мукьва авай астероидар, кентаврар, дамоклоидар, ва гьакӀни Ракъинин системада элячӀна юзазвай кометаяр, метеороидарни космосдин руг. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Ukrainian uk Українська мова}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Со́нячна систе́ма — планетна система, що включає в себе центральну зорю — Сонце, і всі природні космічні об'єкти (планети, астероїди, комети, потоки сонячного вітру тощо), які об'єднуються гравітаційною взаємодією[6]. Сонячна система є частиною значно більшого комплексу, який складається із зірок і міжзоряної речовини — галактики Чумацький Шлях[7].

Сонце складає ≈99,85 \% маси Сонячної системи; газові планети-гіганти (Юпітер, Сатурн, Уран і Нептун) складають 99 \% залишкової маси[8]. Як і в інших зір, у надрах Сонця ефективно відбуваються термоядерні реакції з виділенням енергії[9]. Планети за фізичними характеристиками поділяють на дві групи. Ближче до Сонця розташовані планети земної групи: Меркурій, Венера, Земля, Марс; далі від Сонця розташувались планети-гіганти: Юпітер, Сатурн, Уран, Нептун[10]. Планети земної групи порівняно невеликі, їхня густина ≈5 г/см³; вони складаються переважно з важких хімічних елементів; мають гаряче металеве ядро, оточене мантією із силікатних порід, і верхній шар — кору[11]. Планети-гіганти не мають твердої поверхні, бо за хімічним складом (99 \% гідрогену і гелію) і густиною (≈1 г/см³) вони нагадують зорі, а їхня велика маса спричиняє нагрівання ядер до температури понад +10 000 °С[12].

Окрім Сонця й планет, до складу Сонячної системи входять також карликові планети, супутники планет, астероїди, комети, метеорна речовина[13]. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
{\forig \bfseries Environment: Udmurt udm удмурт кыл}\par
\begin{cyrtranse}
Шунды система — Шундылэсь но со котыртӥ ас спутникъёсынызы бергась 8 бадӟым планетаослэсь, дасо сюрсъёсын пичи планетаослэсь (астероидъёслэсь), быжо кизилиослэсь но метеоръёслэсь кылдэм инмысь система. Со кылдэмын 4,57 млрд пала аръёс талэсь азьло, газ-тузон пилемез гравитациен шымыртыса.

Шунды системалэн ваньмыз массаез луэ ог 1,0014 M☉. Солэн бадӟымез люкетэз Шундылы усе.

Шунды система пыре Лудӟазегсюрес галактикае. 
\end{cyrtranse}
%-------------------------------------------------

%%

Transliteration test:

\begin{multicols}{8}
\testcyrtrans
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```