# How declare a new package language

Tags: xetex, luatex, tex-core

I need writing normal text and some sentences in artifical conscript language.

How writing small as possible package and how use it (include?) in file?
My language have my own font and each glyphs is defined as one or more chars.

K->K

u->ó

sh[number] -> x or x1 or x2 ...

etc

for example:

```
Simple text in english and example :\lang_begin{foo}Kuuejshsh6 2kkkks defefe fg re5rdga'derg gre g \ang_end{foo}
```

If it is possible Lua script to convert char into directly glyph

Comment: Welcome. From the top of my head i would say `verbatim` or a package like  listings` willl do the job. But i am not even sure i understand the question?

Comment: If the string `urgh` means *one* glyph from your special font, better use a screenshot and include that in your document ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B please lokk this http://www.omniglot.com/writing/coptic.htm the letter b or v have this same glyph b, other g,gh,ng have this same glyph g  in my language this is more complicated and I need a script lua to convert normal words to 'my words' ;-)

Comment: As far as i understood that right now, a word is spelled one way, but depending on the context, one letter can have different sounds. You mention a Lua script (in a comment, not the question) for conversion. How will you determin ng in `hong` from ng in `mingong` (*min-gong*). Please add some more explanations to the question (extensive explanation) and also your replacement thingy using Lua.

Comment: I need all sentence. not only word. ng on end of the word is different in middle and different in begining of sentence. I need 2 function in tex \lang_begin \lang_end and one function in lua to convert sentence in my own lang.

Comment: You can use teckit map files for XeTeX and OpenType feature files for Lu aTeX. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285634/2891 for conversion of map files to feature files.

Comment: In which formats have you stored your confonts?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: Added lots of new thoughts and suggestions

As far as I understand your question, you have created a constructed language with a constructed script with own characters not in Unicode. In addition, you have created a transcription of the conscript into latin letters and digits. Now you want to typeset some texts in your conlang.

I suggest that you create a third thing: A LaTeX Input Convention for your constructed language. I suggest using macros, one macro for each character of the constructed script. This is easy to implement, and you can switch the interpretation of the macros for the conscript to the transcription and back.
This way you can typeset your conlang both in its original script and in transcription.

When you have higher programming skills, you may also write a parser for the transcription that outputs your conscript. This is a **difficult task** but it has been done successfully before, e.g., in the ArabTeX package.

You may also want to look into the the babel system of language packages; they offer convenient language specific shorthands to macros. As long as you do not want to include hyphenation, it shouldn't be overly difficult to read off the necessary code changes from one of the language packages with another script (e.g. Russian, Bulgarian, or Greek) to write your own conlang babel package.

Start with the documented `.ldf` (language description file) format and run the `docstrip` utility to get the actual package file.

EDIT: in the LuaTeX context, look at polyglossia instead of babel.

Comment: how create lua script to change input text?

Comment: @Marko Lustro: I don't have specific Lua knowledge, I don't know.  You can specify the input sequence in your font (using ligatures; Greek does this for the vowels with accents and spiritus).

Comment: you may avoid using lua if you try encTeX in 8bit TeXes.

Comment: @Marko Lustro: Look againt at my answer, I have added a lot to it.

Comment: I'd rather insist in using an 8bit encTeX enabled engine; that way you could define `\mubyte\myglyph token [token [token...]] \endmubyte` and have a full transcription for your conscript without Lua.

Comment: An alternative starting point for `babel` is the following tool: http://www.texnia.com/incubator.html .