Changing the directionality of Private User Area characters in the bidi code
I'm building a Hebrew font with about 9,000 additional glyphs. I first wanted to keep them without Unicode assignment and call them through OpenType features, but sadly, their number exceeds Adobe's MakeOTF. So my second thought was to use Unicode PUA ^^^^^0f0000-^^^^^^0ffffd, but when I tried this solution, I found that polyglossia/bidi considers PUA characters as left-to-right by default. So they are breaking the right-to-left direction of my Hebrew words.
Is there someplace in the bidi code where I can change the directionality properties of the PUA characters I need for the given font?
(I'm using XeLaTeX.)
PS. It works when every word starts with a ^^^^200f RTL mark, but I can hardly do that in my document. What I need is a way to change the behavior of some PUA characters in the whole document.

This sounds like a request to the polyglossia maintainer would be in order.

Does babel do the same?

The official bidi algorithm specification https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/ says (§3.2): “Private-use characters can be assigned different values by a conformant implementation”. So somewhere in the bidi package there should be a place to assign directionality to PUA. It is not polyglossia's or babel's task, but part of the bidi algorithm implementation. Does babel use bidi.sty or does it have its own bidi implementation?

it might be simpler to use xetex char classes to insert the direction change, something like this (using a different PUA range where the stix font has visible characters so I can see what's happening) but I'm not at all sure this is doing anything sensible (bidi is confusing:-)

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Math}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\TeXXeTstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \puacc
\newcount\myc
\myc="E000
\loop
\XeTeXcharclass \myc\puacc
\advance\myc 1
\ifnum\myc<"E100
\repeat
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \puacc = {\beginR}
\begin{document}
abc ^^^^e000^^^^e001^^^^e002 xyz
\end{document}`

@yannis With xetex, babel relies on bidi. With luatex, babel has its own implementation and provides a tool to modify the Unicode direction and mirror properties (also linebreak, but that's for CJK). Search the babel manual for \babelcharproperty.

Thanks David and Javier! Maybe some day I will switch to LuaTeX but for now I'm used to TECkit… (it reminds me a bit of Omega Translation Processes…)

@yannis In fact, the ’transform’ mechanism in babel was inspired by the OTPs, although it’s syntax is quite different.

@yannis in LuaTeX you can also add font features to mimic the functionality of TECkit, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285634/264024 for an example, maybe that will help you with the transition?
