# How to automatically adjust the emdash length according to current language?

Tags: fontspec, babel, ligatures, polyglossia

In Russian typography the emdash, which is typed as the ligature `---` in LaTeX, is 20% shorter than the standard emdash. The `babel` package cares this difference so that `---` prints a shorter emdash if `russian` is the current language. However this switch mechanism works only for `latex.exe` engine whereas `lualatex.exe` and `xelatex.exe` type long emdash in any case.

This is because under LaTeX `\selectlanguage{russian}` switches current encoding from, say, `OT1` or `T1` to, say, `T2A`. As a result latin emdash comes from, say, `cmr` font family, whereas russian emdash comes from LH fonts (as a rule). Under LuaTeX or XeLaTeX `\selectlanguage` does not switch current encoding (it remains EU2 for LuaTeX or EU1 for XeTeX) so that `---` always came from same font.

Note however that most fonts contain dashes of different length and, thus, it is possible (in principle) to map `---` to different code points depending on the current script.

**My question is: how to do that using instruments provided by the `fontspec` package?**

Note that `babel` provides a shorthand `"---` (if the `russian` option is indicated) which always types 20% shorter emdash but it also reduces spaces around the emdash and prevents the line break after it.

**UPDATE:**
I have realised that there is no code point in modern Open Type fonts (in contrast to metafont LH fonts used in legacy LaTeX for typesetting cyrillic texts). Both `polyglossia` and `babel` with `russian` option compose a shorter emdash from two endashes, they define a `\cyrdash` macros as follows

```
\def\cyrdash{\hbox to.8em{--\hss--}}
```

and map it to a shorthand `"---`.  So final form of my question is

**How to map the ligature `---` to `\cyrdash`?** Is there any solution except for making the dash `-` active character?

Comment: I guess that this is not doable. `fontspec` can hardly know what language is current one. One could make `-` active character but this is not good solution.

Comment: It seems to me this could be done using XeTeX mapping files and LuaTeX OTF feature files.  See e.g. [Serbian Cyrillic using LuaTeX and XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44709/2693).

Comment: Shouldn't this be the responsibility of a package such as `polyglossia`, which knows the language you are using? Just as it was a responsibility of `babel` in the LaTeX world.

Answer (score 6):

As *nplatis* pointed out, this is actually in the responsibility of `polyglossia`, which works for me, but is more or less font-dependent, as `polyglossia` just uses two “-” `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` and overlaps them, as can be inferred from the `PT Sans` example, where it does not work:

[image: Russian em-dash example (XeLaTeX)]

> The key to getting this to work is to add the `babelshorthands=true` to the language selection, so the code to create the above image is as follows:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{PT Sans}
\setsansfont{PT Sans Caption}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern,babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily{\HT}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily{\GPP}{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily{\BV}{Baskerville}
\newfontfamily{\CCY}{Charcoal CY}

\newcommand{\text}{Слово "--- слово.\\Слово — слово.\par}
%1. babelshorthand/2. U+2014 EM DASH

\begin{document}
PT Sans\\
\text
{\HT Hoefler Text\\
\text}
{\GPP Garamond Premier Pro\\
\text}
{\BV Baskerville\\
\text}
{\CCY Charcoal CY\\
\text}

\end{document}
```

For further information, see also [this thread](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-November/019415.html) in the XeTeX mailing list. Also, `babel` apparently distinguishes several em-dashes for Russian:
`"---`  Cyrillic emdash in plain text.
`"--~`  Cyrillic emdash in compound names (surnames).
`"--*`  Cyrillic emdash for denoting direct speech.
See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Cyrillic_script) for more information.

---

On a side note, I have not succeeded in getting the shorter em-dash in regular LaTeX, just the narrower spacing, strangely enough:

[image: Russian em-dash example (LaTeX)]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}
\noindent
Слово "--- слово.\\
Слово --- слово.\\
Слово — слово.\par% U+2014 EM DASH
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted this anwser altough this is not what I had in mind. I see that it is impossible to map `---` to a code point with a short em-dash (by the way, I did not find short em-dash in Open Type fonts). Also, `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text}` did not work for me until I added `Ligatures={TeX}` option.

Comment: I suppose one would have to resort to a somewhat “hacky” solution, yet this is what `polyglossia` already does. Of course, you could write your own macro with own kerning etc., but I am no expert on this. I have actually not found any code point in Unicode for the shorter em-dash, so I would guess the shorter em-dash—if at all present in a given font—would reside within the Private Use Area (PUA), so additionally, this would become very font-dependent. I really wonder how contemporary Russian typesetters solve this or if they just use the normal em-dash.

Comment: Both polyglossia and babel with russian option compose a shorter em-dash from two emdash as follows: `\def\cyrdash{\hbox to.8em{--\hss--}}`. My question in updated  form is how to map the ligature --- to \cyrdash.

Comment: I disagree. This should mainly be a responsibility of the fonts. When the font is used in a Russian context the dash should be shorter, if this is the usage.

Comment: @egreg I completely agree with you, yet as I have not found any instances of fonts with such capabilities, one has to find a different way to get the expected output or create one’s own font—right now I can only think of the already present `\cyrdash` or some scaling of the regular em-dash. This is definitely something font-creators should take a look at, but this is the first time I ever hear of this phenomenon; even in the Russian Wiki article I could not find any remark towards the reduced-length em-dash, so I reckon it is difficult for typographers to know this if they are not Russian.