# Output for date ranges of publication in biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

Please consider the following

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {Edinburgh},
    title = {I and thou},
    publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
    author = {Buber, Martin},
    translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
    year = {1937},
    origdate = {1923/1924}
}
@incollection{test2,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {Deliberation and democratic legitimacy},
    booktitle = {Deliberative democracy: {Essays} on reason and politics},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Cohen, Joshua},
    editor = {Bohman, James and Rehg, William},
    year = {1997/1998},
    origdate = {1989},
    pages = {67--91}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1} 

\cite{test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and note how the data range is printed

[image]

The data range in APA style (I guess) should be printed like: `Someauthor, 1997-1998`. The problem with `biblatex-apa` style with date ranges is that the `year` field is rendered as `1997/1998`instead of `1997/1998`, while the data ranges for `origdate` is rendered only with the first year `1997`.

How to tweak the style so to output the MWE above as

[image] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, for example:

```
@book{test1,
  address = {Edinburgh},
  title = {I and thou},
  publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
  author = {Buber, Martin},
  translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
  year = {1937},
  related = {test1orig},
  relatedtype = {reprintfrom}
}

@book{test1orig,
  address = {OrigPlace},
  title = {I and thou},
  publisher = {OrigPublisher},
  author = {Buber, Martin},
  translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
  date = {1923/1924}
}
```

With this, I get:

[image]

Which is correct. APA style doesn't put the year of the reprint in there but if you wanted to do this, you can just modify the `related:reprintfrom` macro in apa.bbx.

Answer (score 1):

A few things will fix most of this.

First, I suggest you rearrange the load order of `babel`-`csquotes`-`biblatex`; something like this, perhaps:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71517/8528
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
style=apa,
backend=biber,
isbn=false,
url=false,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
hyperref=true, % <-- not loaded in original question
backref=false,
firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

The other problem is in the `.bib` entries themselves.  You have in `test2`:

```
year = {1997/1998},
origdate = {1989},
```

But you want:

```
date = {1997/1998},
origdate = {1989},
```

For your second reference, you will now get in your citation:

> Cohen, 1989/1997–1998

and in your bibliography:

> Cohen, J. (1997–1998). Deliberation and democratic legitimacy. In J. Bohman
>   & W. Rehg (Eds.), *Deliberative democracy: Essays on reason and politics*
>   (pp. 67–91). Cambridge, MA: MIT Press. (Original work published 1989)

The problem with `test1` is, I think, that the `APA` style does not care about about the `origendyear` and so it just prints the `origyear`, which, according to the `biblatex` manual, by default just takes the first date if a range is given.

I hesitate to suggest a fix since I'm not sure if this is a 'feature' of the APA style in general or a bug in the implementation of that style.

Comment: It's just that this is better handled by the biblatex "related entries" feature so you have separate entries for the original and the reprint/translation/whatever. Then the style doesn't have to mess about parsing/merging dates and origdates etc.

Comment: @PLK -- I thought, on balance, that there was likely a reason for the setup, which is why I didn't try to suggest a 'fix' --- especially since I don't use APA.  However, adding `related` and `relatedtype` fields to entry `test1` and then adding a `test1orig` entry with the `date = {1923/1924},` still gives the date '1937' as the date of the reprint entry..?  Should I open a new question or GitHub ticket?

Comment: Can you add a MWE for the related entry version?

Comment: @PLK -- Replace `test1` in the OP with: `@book{test1,
    address = {Edinburgh},
    title = {I and thou},
    publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
    author = {Buber, Martin},
    translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
    year = {1937},
    related = {test1orig},
    relatedtype = {reprintof},
}`.  And add: `@book{test1orig,
    address = {OrigPlace},
    title = {I and thou},
    publisher = {OrigPublisher},
    author = {Buber, Martin},
    translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
    date = {1923/1924},
}`. Everything else can be kept the same, although my test file contains the changed preamble.

Comment: It should be `{reprintfrom}` - see the answer - I had to paste in PDF screenshot.

Comment: @PLK -- Ah, I see.  I don't actually use APA (nor do I know the style guidelines!), so I didn't know that it would need `reprintfrom` or that the original date wouldn't be mentioned.  In history, reprints are often 'facsimile reprints' of much older editions (say from the 1500s), and so original place of publication and year are fundamental bibliographical information (since a work was often (re-)printed in different places and the editions -- let alone pagination -- were rarely the same).