# change header style of bibliography page

Tags: bibliographies, fancyhdr, header

My LaTeX looks as follows (I omit somethings):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter

\title{\textsc{AAAZZZ}}
\author{LZ}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
The goal of this notes is to describe \ldots

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I offer my sincerest gratitude to \ldots

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Preliminaries on A}

\chapter{Results on Z}

\appendix

\chapter{More results on Z}

\backmatter

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

My bibliography has 2 pages, the (right part of the) header of its 2nd page looks like "B. Bibliography" (the left part of the header on the same page is the page number). How do I change it to "Bibliography" only (eliminating "B. ")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

just before the beginning of the bibliography should work.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how to use French and possible other languages with accents, in the English text, like "étale, Ngô Bảo Châu", in my above setting (not use `\'etale` etc. each time, because I use that quite often)?

Comment: I write almost all of my documents in french, and by adding ``\usepackage[french]{babel} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`` in the preamble everything always works. However it's been a long time since I've asked myself any questions about that (these lines have been on all of my documents since I begun to use LaTeX), so I don't really remember how it works. If it doesn't work for you, maybe you will find an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71517/do-i-need-fontenc-and-inputenc) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc).

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, in fact, I tried that before. Maybe because I'm using amsbook, but that works for article class only. I will see your link to see if they work.