# Pound = $ if tgpagella and utf8 loaded: why?

Tags: unicode, font-encodings

I am trying to have the pound sign appear in text composed with TG Pagella.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella} % alternative to MinionPro
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  The pound sign one way : \pounds, or another \textsterling
\end{document}
```

produces a dollar sign. however if I change `[utf8]{inputenc}` into `[t1]{fontenc}`, I do get a nice pound sign.
question: Why is that so?
doesn't Pagella support utf8?
Is it OK to use `T1` and `fontenc` together with Pagella? Any issues?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc for the difference between `inputenc` and `fontenc`: both are useful, but for separate tasks.

Answer (score 7):

As JosephWright explained, you can perfectly well use both `inputenc` and `fontenc`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% generally best to load this before loading the font
\usepackage{tgpagella}% alternative to MinionPro
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  The pound sign one way : \pounds, or another \textsterling
\end{document}
```

`inputenc` sets the *input* encoding i.e. how the characters you type are encoded. `fontenc` sets the *output* encoding which tells TeX where in the font particular glyphs should be.

The reason you get a dollar sign when you do not load `fontenc` with the `T1` encoding is that you are then using the default encoding, `OT1` *and* there appears to be at least one bug, but probably two, in the font configuration for `tgpagella` (and probably the other TeX-Gyre fonts since they all share the same encoding files).

`OT1` only has 128 slots whereas `T1` has 256. This means that there is not room for both the dollar and pound sign. Originally, TeX could not deal with encodings containing more than 128 characters. The way TeX originally coped with this limitation was to put the dollar sign in the upright font and the pound sign in the italic. So if `OT1` is active (e.g. because you don't load `fontenc` with another encoding), your code will produce dollar signs instead of pound signs because the dollar occupies that slot in the upright font. To avoid this, LaTeX uses the following code:

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\textsterling}{OT1}{\hmode@bgroup
   \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
      \itshape
   \else
      \fontshape{ui}\selectfont
   \fi
   \char`\$\egroup}
```

and further defines `\pounds` in terms of either `\mathsterling` or `\textsterling` depending on whether you are in maths mode or not.

So `\pounds` and `\textsterling` should behave as expected. However, it does not. For some reason, TeX tries to load the `ui` shape for `tgpagella`. Since this doesn't exist, it substitutes the upright shape which, of course, gives you the dollar sign. This suggests that the relevant font dimension has not be set correctly as the code should cause it to try `\itshape` rather than attempting to load the non-existent `ui` shape. However, even if you force `\itshape`, you do not get a sterling sign but, rather, an italic dollar. So the configuration has apparently put an italic dollar in the italic font for the `OT1` encoding rather than the upright sterling sign.

Avoiding such complexities is one reason `T1` is recommended. Others include the fact that many accented characters are included in `T1` whereas if you use `OT1`, TeX has to create them from the unaccented glyph plus an accent. This is less satisfactory in terms of both the visual appearance (in many cases) and copy-and-paste. Again, this is because of limitations imposed by the 128 slot limit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. See my corrections. I think there are two bugs in tgpagella.

Answer (score 5):

Don't ignore latex warnings:-)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}% generally best to load this before loading the font
\usepackage{tgpagella}% alternative to MinionPro
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  The pound sign one way : \pounds, or another \textsterling
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/qpl/m/ui' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/qpl/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

In OT1 encoding, italic fonts have a `£` and non italic fonts have a `$` So LaTeX2e, to avoid having a default slanted *£* (as LaTeX2.09 and plain TeX did) uses an upright italic font. But most font sets don't have that so the font mechanism is substituting it

It is unfortunately substituting upright roman (`m/n`)  so losing the pound, it would be better to substitute italic

You could add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{qpl}{m}{ui}{<->sub*qpl/m/it}{}}
```

then the substitution is

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/qpl/m/ui' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/qpl/m/it' tried instead on input line 7.
```

But it seems that you still get a $ which is arguably an error in teh internal font encoding for OT1 in this font, but really there is no reason to use OT1 encoding at all, it is just there to cope with the interesting features of the encodings used by the Computer Modern fonts, so switching to T1 makes the problem go away.

Comment: It isn't LaTeX's fault it is substituting `ui`, I don't think. I believe this is due to a second bug in `tgpagella`. What LaTeX does is actually dependent on a font dimension which I think must be configured incorrectly in this case. Otherwise, you would see this problem for any font lacking the `ui` shape. But you don't. (The standard Times look-alike, for example, gets this right but there is no `ui` shape.) So if it were set correctly, it would try `\itshape` given the code from the base configuration for OT1. (See my edited answer.)