# Error in compiling

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, font-encodings, input-encodings

I'm starting to use latex, my code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}
 Hello
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\Stefano1\Desktop\Seminario\Seminario.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"

! LaTeX Error: File `T1.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name:
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: I don't think `T1` is a valid option for `inputenc`.

Comment: So what should I write instead of T1 ?

Comment: Since you are starting using LaTeX, please read some tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [inputenc package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenc)

> allows the user to specify an input encoding (for example,
>   ASCII, ISO Latin-1 or Macintosh) by saying:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[encoding name]{inputenc}
> ```

The choices of encoding name are listed on pages 1-2 of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

A typical italian preamble may instead be

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

than followed by any

```
\begin{document}
 Hello
\end{document}
```

(first comment by Ian Thompson is definitely right).

...but I am sure that, by today, you've learnt better than me the [difference between
**input encoding** and **font encoding**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc).