# scrlttr2 - bad format

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

i have the following formatting problem writing a cover letter, using  scrttr2`.
The main text is very long, but as you can see from the given example - there is a lot of unused space. I want the letter fit to one page; for example by reducing the space to the bottom edge.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,version=last,ich]{scrlttr2} %Standard: 12 DIV, BOIC 0%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % erkennen von Umlauten %
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Silbentrennung nach deutschem Standard %
\usepackage{charter} %Schriftart%
\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off,fromrule=false} % die hässlichen Striche am Rand wegmachen %
\setkomavar{backaddress}{}  % die Unterstreichung der eigenen Adresse weglassen % 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomavar{place}{Mars}        % um den Ort hinzuzufügen %
\setkomavar{fromname}{Space Cowboy}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Milkiway 5\\
 99999 Town}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} % um die Unterschrift bündig zu machen %
% so kann man den Text direkt unter die Anschrift setzen
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in} % in sind inch %
% how can i change this - ist there a more elegant way???
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempskipa}{-12ex}%
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{\@tempskipa}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempskipa}{-12ex}%
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{\@tempskipa}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempskipa}{12ex}%
\@addtoplength{firstfootvpos}{\@tempskipa}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{letter} {
Sausage Shop\\ 
Recruiting Management\\ 
Mr Sausage \\
Street 5 \\
99999 Town\\
}
\opening{Dear Mr Sausage,}
\blindtext
\\
\blindtext 
\\
\blindtext
\closing{Greets,\\}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlagen}
\encl{Notenspiegel, Excelschein}
\end{letter}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: Please reduce your code,  e.g. Do not post random text,  use blind text for this

Comment: But the exaple fits very good to my orginal text. should i write xxx... instead? - Sorry i'm new

Comment: `\usepackage{blindtext} ` in the preamble and `\blindtext` in the document

Comment: There are many strange things you do there. A question: do you want to use a windowed envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few caveats in your code. First some general hints:

- do not use `\\` in text. It is not a marker for a new paragraph. Just leave a single empty line in the code.
- Your comments are misleading mostly.
- you should also use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` when using pdflatex.
- never use `\setlength{evensidemargin}{}` or `\setlength{oddsidemargin}{}`, especially in a letter they make no sense at all. letters are one-sided by default. More on this in the l2tabu: ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf
- `\setkomavar{backaddress}{}` does not remove the underlining, it removes your address from the address window completely.
- the ugly stripes are actually the marks where you have to fold the paper to fit it into a regular envelope, might be helpful.

If you do not use a windowed envelope, you do not need the address field, and the result fits on one page if you remove it and the space it takes:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,11pt,version=last]{scrlttr2}

% this tells LaTeX the source file's encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% this does way more then loading german hyphenation
% e.g. it changes names (Tabelle instead of Table etc.)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off, fromrule=false}

\setkomavar{place}{Mars}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Space Cowboy}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
  Milkiway 5\\
  99999 Town%
}

%remove addrfield and its space
\KOMAoptions{addrfield=false}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
  Sausage Shop\\ 
  Recruiting Management\\ 
  Mr Sausage \\
  Street 5 \\
  99999 Town\\
}
\opening{Dear Mr Sausage,}
\blindtext

\blindtext 

\blindtext
\closing{Greets}
\encl{Notenspiegel, Excelschein}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Max, but what does \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} make? Please answer in key words :)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `DINmtext.lco` to save space. See the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), section "Letter Class Option Files" for more information.

If there is no firstfoot you can set `firstfoot=false` and `enlargefirstpage`.

Use the package `geometry` to change the pagelayout:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=\useplength{toaddrhpos},bottom=2cm}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
%  ich,
  DINmtext,
  foldmarks=off,
  fromrule=off,
  backaddress=off,
  firstfoot=off,
  enlargefirstpage
]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{charter}

\setkomavar{place}{Mars}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Space Cowboy}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Milkiway 5\\99999 Town}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=\useplength{toaddrhpos},bottom=2cm}

\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{-2\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter} {
Sausage Shop\\ 
Recruiting Management\\ 
Mr Sausage \\
Street 5 \\
99999 Town\\
}
\opening{Dear Mr Sausage,}
\blindtext

\blindtext 

\blindtext
\closing{Greets,\\}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlagen}
\encl{Notenspiegel, Excelschein}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i used this soution. Please explain in key points what  DINmtext means?

Comment: `DINmtext.lco` is a Letter Class Option File that is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. `scrlttr2` loads automatically `DIN.lco` which sets the parameters for letters on A4 paper complying the German DIN 676 standard. `DINmtext.lco` changes the parameter to use a different layout with more text on the first page. It complies also the German DIN. Because of the changed address position it is only suitable for window envelopes C6 and C6/5 (but not C4 and C5 window envelopes).

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `enlargefirstpage` as documented, but please don't.

Sometimes, you have to accept, that some things don't fit. I don't know about Mr. Sausage, but `tfl` gets furious looking at this.

[image: jogiLetter]

Comment: hey Johannes,thanks for your reply! But where do i need to set the "tf1" option? - could your give the code example

Comment: @Jogi there is non. `tfl` is an acronym for *tasty fried liver*  ;-) https://github.com/johannesbottcher/bausteineBewerbung/blob/master/beispiel.pdf

Comment: btw, I would choose the answer by @esdd, it is far better ;-)