# pdfx option clash inputenc + fontenc + hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf-a, pdfx

I want to compile my `.tex` file with `pdflatex` but get an option clash, since I load `pdfx` to get a PDF/A-1b compliant file.

This is part of my header:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,DIV15,parskip=off,9pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
linktocpage=false,      % no page numbers are clickable
colorlinks=false,       % no color
breaklinks=true,        % break URLs
bookmarks,              % creates bookmarks in pdf
hyperfootnotes=true,    % clickable footnotes
pdfborder={0 0 0},      % for removing borders around links
bookmarksnumbered=true, % If Acrobat bookmarks are requested, include section numbers.
bookmarksopen=false,    % If Acrobat bookmarks are requested, show them with all the subtrees expanded.
%hidelinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,
%citecolor=blue,
%urlcolor=blue
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}, % show pdf bookmarks (indices) on startup; does not function all the time
pdftitle={...}, % title
pdfauthor={...}, % author
pdfkeywords={...}, % subject of the document
pdfsubject={...}, % list of keywords
pdfmenubar=true]        % make PDF viewer’s menu bar visible
{hyperref}
\usepackage{url} % Urls become clickable
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelabels}

% ------
% Fonts and typesetting settings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % libertine font as pbk (=Garamond font, ugm) substitution
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{pbk} % to change the headers and body texts
\usepackage{mathpazo} % palatino font as pbk (=Optima font, pbk) substitution
%\linespread{1.05}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % removes this restriction by allowing font sizes at arbitrary sizes
\usepackage{mycals}
\usepackage{ngerman} % new german spelling

\begin{document}
foobar here
\end{document}
```

**Bonus question:** I did not get the difference of `inputenc` and `fontenc` but I know that I have to insert both packages for this document. Otherwise I would run into issues with the fonts.

Comment: See [`fontenc` vs `inputenc`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/) for your bonus question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get no error if I load the packages in the correct order:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,DIV15,parskip=off,9pt]{scrbook}
% Fonts and typesetting settings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % For Palatino
%\usepackage{mycals} % What's this????

\usepackage[
  linktocpage=false,      % no page numbers are clickable
  colorlinks=false,       % no color
  breaklinks=true,        % break URLs
  bookmarks,              % creates bookmarks in pdf
  hyperfootnotes=true,    % clickable footnotes
  pdfborder={0 0 0},      % for removing borders around links
  bookmarksnumbered=true, % If Acrobat bookmarks are requested, include section numbers.
  bookmarksopen=false,    % If Acrobat bookmarks are requested, show them with all the subtrees expanded.
  %hidelinks=true,
  %linkcolor=blue,
  %citecolor=blue,
  %urlcolor=blue,
  pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}, % show pdf bookmarks (indices) on startup; does not function all the time
  pdftitle={...}, % title
  pdfauthor={...}, % author
  pdfkeywords={...}, % subject of the document
  pdfsubject={...}, % list of keywords
  pdfmenubar=true,        % make PDF viewer’s menu bar visible
  pdfpagelabels,
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\urlstyle{same}

% ------

\begin{document}
foobar here
\end{document}
```

Note that `hyperref` should be loaded as late as possible, with some exceptions such as `pdfx` and `cleveref`.

Also `\usepackage{ngerman}` should be replaced by `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and it doesn't make sense to load `libertine` and doing `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pbk}` if you later do `\usepackage{mathpazo}`. No need to load `url`, because it's already loaded by `hyperref`.

I'm not sure what you think `pbk` means: it's the symbolic name for Bookman.

I commented `mycals`, as I know nothing about it.

Comment: Thanks egreg, it functions now! I need `pbk` for a slightly different type setting in some parts of the book. I added the suggestion you made. `mycals` is a `sty` I wrote for some styling and only forgot to remove it from the minimal example.

Answer (score 5):

With pdfx.sty (v1.5.8) the following order of packages works also,
provided you change the `\usepackage[..options..]{hyperref}` into `\hypersetup{..options..}`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,DIV15,parskip=off,9pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
% Fonts and typesetting settings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % For Palatino
...
\hypersetup{%
  linktocpage=false,      % no page numbers are clickable
  colorlinks=false,       % no color
 ...
}
```

I've put a lot of work, within `pdfx.sty`, into ensuring compatibility with other packages, and am doing further work to allow it to be loaded at any point within the LaTeX preamble. So I'd appreciate notification of any incompatibility that anyone encounters. Example documents are just what I need.

Comment: I just added `\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}` to a custom class I am developing and suddenly got an option clash for `[utf8x]{inputenc}` so I switched the order of my inputenc and fontenc lines as suggested, but the error still occurs. Email me and I'll send you the example.

Comment: Interestingly I cannot reproduce this with the (partial) code block above. In any case, the recommended work-around is: "\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}"  before the "\documentclass",  then you won't need the "\usepackage" as it will be loaded anyway by pdfx.sty .

Comment: You mean I won't need the `\usepackage{inputenc}`? I had tried with `\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8x}{inputenc}` but I didn't realise `pdfx.sty` loaded `inputenc`.

Comment: Umm. Two problems with that: (a) it gags on `\PrerenderUnicode{š}` and half a dozen similar, saying Undefined control sequence. \305->\UTFviii@two@octets; and (b) it also gags on an ellipsis character (LaTeX Error: Command \dots unavailable in encoding T1) and a pound sterling character (LaTeX Error: Command \pounds unavailable in encoding T1).

Comment: If you download http://latex.silmaril.ie/examples/test.cls and test.tex you'll see the problem. My test.log is there too.

Comment: @PeterFlynn Firstly you are using an old `pdfx.sty`.  `(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty
Package: pdfx 2016/02/04 v1.5.6 PDF/X and PDF/A support (CVR/HTH/RRM/PS)`. The current version with TeXLive 2017 is `1.5.84`.

Comment: @PeterFlynn  Even with the later version there is a problem with `\pounds`, but there are easy work-arounds.  One is to use  `\let\pounds\textsterling` when `pdfx.sty` is loaded.  Alternatively your class file can have:  `\let\realLTXpounds\pounds
  \RequirePackage[x-1a]{pdfx}
  \let\pounds\realLTXpounds`.
Let me know it you come across any other commands like this. The concept of "pseudo-encoding", as needed by both `hyperref` and `pdfx` is being tackled by the LaTeX team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62772/discussion-between-ozross-rrm-and-peter-flynn).