# umlaute not rendered correctly with lualatex

Tags: luatex, unicode

I'm creating a presentation with LaTeX beamer in German.

I've read this answer about Umlaute: [German character not rendered to pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40962/german-character-not-rendered-to-pdf)

But I still have some issues.

This is my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\begin{document}
\section{äöüßÄÖÜ "a"o"u"s"A"O"U}
\begin{frame}{ä ö ü ß Ä Ö Ü "a "o "u "s "A "O "U} 
\tableofcontents
\Huge
ä ö ü ß Ä Ö Ü "a "o "u "s "A "O "U
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and this is the resulting PDF translated with LuaLaTeX:

[image]

as you can see there are 2 issues:

1. The UTF-8 `ß` is always resolved to SS while all the other Umlaute render correctly.
2. The PDF content view never renders UTF-8 Umlaute correctly.

my latex version is:

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)
```

how can I fix the Umlaut problem other than changing all Umlaute to their `"x` form?

**[edit]**
The answer given here [Using LuaTeX as a replacement for pdfTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32295/using-luatex-as-a-replacement-for-pdftex) solves the problem, but does not address the "Umlaut" problem explicitly so that I was not able to find it.

Comment: Don't load `fontenc` or `inputenc` when using LuaLaTeX.  See [Using LuaTeX as a replacement for pdfTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32295/2693).

Comment: use `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` instead

Comment: @AlanMunn this solves the `ß` problem for the slides themselves, but the content view in PDF viewer is still broken.

Comment: @thewaywewalk thanks, this solves the content viewer problem too.

Comment: @thewaywewalk maybe you will be interested into commenting the answers provided to my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282678/why-does-inputenc-abandon-so-quickly-under-utf8-based-engines

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- The bookmarks are fixed with `hyperref` option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto`. The options can be given to option `hyperref` of class `beamer` that passes the options to the package `hyperref`.
- Assuming the text is written in UTF-8, package `inputenc` must be removed for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Both are already using UTF-8.
- Font encoding `T1` is better than `OT1` with non-Unicode TeX compilers, because it supports some accented letters (umlauts). The recommendation for LuaTeX or XeTeX is package `fontspec`, because they support TrueType and OpenType Unicode fonts. The default fonts are then Latin Modern, which are derived from the Computer Modern fonts (e.g., a much larger range of accented characters are supported).

Full example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{äöüßÄÖÜ "a"o"u"s"A"O"U}
\begin{frame}{ä ö ü ß Ä Ö Ü "a "o "u "s "A "O "U}
\tableofcontents
\Huge
ä ö ü ß Ä Ö Ü "a "o "u "s "A "O "U
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: is it possible to set the `,hyperref={unicode}` option in the preamble instead  of the `documentclass` itself?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle No, it's to late after `\documentclass`, because `hyperref` is already loaded by the class. Alternatives: The option can be specified in a configuration file `hyperref.cfg` or it can be given before `\documentclass` by `\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}`.

Comment: I'd like to invite you to this [follow up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338781/can-we-stop-recommend-fontspec-as-first-choice-in-case-lualatex-is-used).

Comment: +1: I have the same problem but I use the newer `\usepackage{bookmark}`. The options you mention (`unicode` and `pdfencoding=auto`) are not mentioned in the (bookmark) manual and throw an (useful) error message. I now added the `hyperref` package and this solved the problem but I am not sure if that's the way you intended to use the `bookmark` package (using `hyperref` and `bookmark` at the same time).

Comment: The options `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto` belong to package `hyperref`. Package `bookmark` loads package `hyperref` (because of `\pdfstringdef`).

Answer (score 12):

If you use **lualatex** but you're not planning to use unicode fonts by means of loading the `fontspec` package, you should load

```
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
```

instead of `inputenc`.

If you actually want to use unicode fonts, loading `fontspec` is sufficient and neither `luainputenc` nor `fontenc` are needed.

---

Apart from that, I disagree with the often given general recommendation *not to load* `fontenc` in case lualatex is used.*

Because the necessity of this package does not depend on the compiler used, but whether or not the `fontspec` package is loaded.

The majority of people use lualatex because of the `fontspec` package, as it enables the use of *unicode fonts*. But there are people, like me, using lualatex because of the ability to deal with lua-code (and other advantages...), but don't like to use unicode fonts (as it is slow, and other disadvantages...). In the latter case you still could need `fontenc`.

*[Here you can find a further discussion on this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338781/36835).

Comment: @AlanMunn You're right, I hope my edit made it clearer. What bothers me is the phrase for "*for most users the advice to use fontspec ... is more practical*"  - which I read very often, because it implies that you *should* load `fontspec` when you use lualatex, which is absolutely not the case. Working in a language with lots of umlauts using lualatex saves you so much problems, but fontspec creates so much new problems. I got into that trap and tried so solve them, before I found out, not using `fontspec` is much more convenient and faster.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer.  I'll delete my original comment.