# Is it OK to use packages like newtxtext or babel in LuaTeX and XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, spanish

I usually use `newtxtext` for most of my documents, but I'm trying to switch to XeTeX from pdfLaTeX.
The Unicode characters ¿ and ¡ show up as £ and ą when using `newtxtext` on LuaTex and XeTeX, so I just use `fontspec` now.
Note that this doesn't happen if I enter the characters with the standard commands like `\textquestiondown`. I assume this is just some sort of incompatibility with the new engines, although I haven't read anywhere that they shouldn't be used in these.

[[image: 1]]

Likewise, I'm also following the practice of using `polyglossia` instead of `babel` because I've read `polyglossia` is designed as the successor for `babel` in XeTeX, but **is there any real reason not to keep using `babel` on the new engines?** Why is there two big packages for the same task?

Thankfully I doubt I would have any big problems or incompatibilities caused by Spanish localization, since it's just Latin script with diacritics already supported in TeX, but I can imagine CJK-languages would be more prone to problems like this.

Small example of `newtxtext` not working right on XeTeX or LuaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
«¡¿Por—qué?!»

\guillemotleft\textexclamdown\textquestiondown{}Por---qu\'e?!\guillemotright
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf) for newtx on CTAN. It includes examples of how to set the package up for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX in Section 5 on page 10.

Comment: Could you post a small document that gives us something to start from?

Comment: @John Very useful link, but please don't link to specific mirrors: link to the round-robin instead.

Comment: You can use Babel. Polyglossia doesn't support all languages supported by Babel (yet?). Polyglossia requires Xe/LuaTeX, so isn't usable with older engines. You seem to know all this already, so surely it is obvious why there are two packages: they don't do the same thing, even though they may serve the same purpose in some cases. Using standard text font packages is not recommended. (If you have to ask if it is OK, you shouldn't be doing it.) But standard maths packages are fine. For text/maths packages, care is needed as the linked manual shows.

Comment: @Teepeemm not quite sure what do you mean, but I added a small example for the characters «¡¿—» with newtxtext

Comment: @John thanks for the link, but I've already seen it. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but it doesn't seem to matter the order I load the packages. Ironically, the package libertine _does_ work fine, but if I load fontenc opposite as it is shown in the examples there, not quite sure why.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, I still use newtxmath. I'd rather use newtxtext than loading Times New Roman through fontspec since I find the former's font much pleasing on the end result.

Comment: Not all font packages are a bad idea. Some, like `libertine`, detect if running under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and use `fontspec` and system fonts in that case. But you can't always know if a package does this. AFAICS `newtxtext` does not do special things for Xe/LuaLaTeX and should probably not be used, `newtxmath` on the other hand can do stuff for these two engines and can be used with the appropriate settings. You also don't load `fontenc` and `inputenc` with Xe/LuaLaTeX, but that doesn't change anything here. BTW: `netxtext` is based on the open type font `TeXGyre Termes` so you might try that

Comment: Re `babel` v `polyglossia`. There are some things `polyglossia` does better than babel, especially for languages with non-Latin scripts (I'm thinking of RTL languages like Arabic, Hebrew, ...). And there are some things that `babel` still does better than `polyglossia`. Amongst those is the interface for other packages. At the moment `polyglossia` is only occasionally maintained and has many open bug reports and feature requests, while `babel` is actively being developed (with progress on the RTL front). If `babel` worked for you before there is no real reason to switch to `polyglossia`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
```

never use `[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex or luatex this specifies that you want to use a legacy tex-specific 8-bit font encoding, so undoes almost all of xetex's Unicode support. You will get incorrect characters (as you saw) and incorrect hyphenation for any non-ascii text even if the characters appear correct.

`[utf8]{inputenc}` does nothing in luatex or xetex other than issue a warning that it shouldn't be used.

Font packages such as `newtxtext` mostly shouldn't be used as mostly font packages for pdflatex are setting up the fonts that have been re-encoded for TeX in encodings such as T1, but some are OK to use as they detect the TU (unicode0 encoding and load Unicode (typically OpenType) versions of the fonts. As I just noticed moewe said in comments using TeXGyre Termes via `fontspec` effectively gives you the OpenType base font on which the textext fonts were based.

`babel` is fine, `polyglossia` is/was developed as an alternative to `babel` but currently `babel` is more actively maintained, so try both and see which you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. This sums up my concerns. I've been switching to polyglossia, but since people here seem to mention it's perfectly fine to use babel, I may have to switch back, after all, the Spanish support IS better there. It's an infortunate situation that something like UTF-8 (or Unicode) support is so hard to get working on older TeX engines, but I assume it's something way too intrinsic with the inners-workings of the engines.

Comment: @ficion the restriction to a maximum of at most 256 characters per font is built into the core of tex and built in to its syntax for almost all core commands and character handling such as `\char` and `\mathchardef`  so supporting a Unicode font is necessarily a breaking change. There is a reason luatex and xetex are new systems not just an updated (pdf)tex.

Answer (score 3):

To explain somewhat why the output differs, consider this example, using only the `¿`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\tracingmacros1
¿
\tracingmacros0

\showoutput
\end{document}
```

If you compile with XeLaTeX, the log contains no trace of macro expansion. And the `\showoutput` contains a line

```
....\T1/lmr/m/n/10 ¿
```

If you compile with PDFLaTeX, the log contains this (as explained below the log file is considered iso-latin-1 encoded in that case by Emacs and decoded as such, but what is pasted here is the utf-8 encoded conversion)

```
Â->\UTFviii@two@octets Â

\UTFviii@two@octets #1#2->\expandafter \UTFviii@defined \csname u8:#1\string #2
\endcsname 
#1<-Â
#2<-¿

\UTFviii@defined #1->\ifx #1\relax \if \relax \expandafter \UTFviii@checkseq \s
tring #1\relax \relax \UTFviii@undefined@err {#1}\else \PackageError {inputenc}
{Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence}\UTFviii@invalid@help \fi \else \expandafter #1\fi

#1<-\u8:Â¿ 

\u8:Â¿ ->\IeC {\textquestiondown }

\IeC ->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \@firstofone \else \noexpan
d \IeC \fi 

\@firstofone #1->#1
#1<-\textquestiondown 

\textquestiondown ->\T1-cmd \textquestiondown \T1\textquestiondown 

\T1-cmd #1->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \@inmathwarn #1\else \noexpand #1\e
xpandafter \@gobble \fi 
#1<-\textquestiondown 

\@inmathwarn #1->\ifmmode \@latex@warning {Command \protect #1 invalid in math 
mode}\fi 
#1<-\textquestiondown
```

and one finds also

```
....\T1/cmr/m/n/10 ¾
```

in the log.

About the weird `¾` it is because my Emacs/AUCTeX considers the log file to be `iso-latin-1` encoded and this is character at slot `190`. The buffer from which I copied pasted actually uses UTF-8: `buffer code: #xC2 #xBE` but `file code: #xBE (encoded by coding system iso-latin-1-unix)`.

On the other hand `¿` has UTF-8 representation `file code: #xC2 #xBF (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)`, and we see above how this creates a lot of agitation at (PDF)LaTeX+inputenc[utf8] side to convert the `0xBF` (191) to `0xBE`(190) which matches the actual location in T1 font encoding.

On the other hand in the XeLaTeX case, `inputenc` does nothing in case of `utf8` and as a result the `191` remains `191` and we get to see in PDF the glyph which happens to be at slot location `191` in T1-font encoding.

Notice also that if we query the meaning of `\T1\textquestiondown` in the PDFLaTeX case via

```
\expandafter\show\csname T1\string\textquestiondown\endcsname
```

we get this in log:

```
> \T1\textquestiondown=\char"BE.
<recently read> \T1\textquestiondown 

l.16 ...sname T1\string\textquestiondown\endcsname
```

where we find indeed the `0xBE=190` which is T1 slot for `¿`.

Related: [Why does inputenc abandon so quickly under "utf8 based engines"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282678/why-does-inputenc-abandon-so-quickly-under-utf8-based-engines)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this insightful answer, this was what I was actually wondering about fontenc on XeTeX, as I thought it'd try to do the same work as in pdfTeX. I'm currently trying to learn more about how macros work inside, so this is very helpful; thanks again.