# Umlaute with biblatex not displayed

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have the following Bibtex source:

```
  @Book{sarndal_estimation_2005,
  Title                    = {Estimation in {Surveys} with {Nonresponse}},
  Author                   = {S{\"a}rndal, Carl-Erik and Lundstr{\"o}m, Sixten},
  Publisher                = {Wiley},
  Year                     = {2005},

  Address                  = {Chichester}
```

I use the following Latex preamble

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
```

However the umlaute in the author names are simply omitted despite the correct representation in bibtex code. Do I need to enter them differently for biblatex?

[image]

Comment: Do you have both `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`? Or neither.

Comment: I think I have neither

Comment: I added them, the umlaute are there now. But the font is changed and looks strange.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example that shows failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example (with `example.bib` being your provided bib example) should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sarndal_estimation_2005}
\end{document}
```

When using `T1` as input encoding, `lmodern` gives you access to the Latin Modern font family, which prevents the "strange look", cf. also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44701/99345

Comment: Perfect answer adressing the strange font type as well, thank you.