# missing accented characters lualatex in texlive2016

Tags: errors, luatex, unicode, accents

If I process the following beamer class with lualatex (texlive 2016), the `Á` charactert is missing in the output pdf, but `í` appears correctly.
This problem is not showing with laulatex of texlive 2015.

The following warning appears in the log file

{/home/zunbeltz/texlive/texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}
Missing character: There is no Á (U+00C1) in font cmr10!

The MWE is saves as utf-8 file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Ángel
\item Pedro Rodr\'{\i}guez
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{fontspec}`. By the way, typing `Rodr\'iguez` has been possible for several years.

Comment: @egreg: Shouldn't this be done automatically by beamer by detecting luatex? Do you think I should open a bug against beamer?

Comment: Where's `beamer` mentioned in your example? Anyway, I don't think you can blame `beamer`: if you use the class with LuaLaTeX you should know that some setting is needed.

Comment: Why "Ángel" (utf-8) but not "Rodríguez"?

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I first show the problem with `beamer` and later notice that it was also with `article`. Why was it working fine with tl2015 and not tl2016? (I guess is all the changes in luatex 0.95). From the `fontspec` manual: "The fontspec package allows users of either XeTeX or LuaTeX to load OpenType fonts in a LaTeX document." In this case we are using the standard fonts in LaTeX; so, shouldn't the LaTeX kernel do the job to typeset this fine without loading `fontspec` manually?

Comment: @JLDiaz: To show that the problem is with the "utf8" characters.

Comment: @TeXtnik But, then... did `\'Angel` work?

Comment: @egreg: I think I have to apologise! It is not working with TL2015! I think I was confused by several changes between TL2015 and TL2016.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Yes it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I compile the following example with LuaLaTeX from TeX Live 2015

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item \'Angel
\item Ángel
\item Pedro Rodr\'{\i}guez
\item Pedro Rodríguez
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

which is expected.

If I add also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the output is

[image]

but it is pure luck (see [fontenc vs inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc) for an explanation).

Always load `fontspec` when compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item \'Angel
\item Ángel
\item Pedro Rodr\'{\i}guez
\item Pedro Rodríguez
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]