# How to write multiple symbols in \textsc

Tags: pdftex

I am writing `\textsc{<someother\_thing> }` and want same output in small caps keeping symbols intact. `\_` is used to output only `_`. The output I get is `¡SOMEOTHER_THING¿` and there is no error.

I want output as `<SOMEOTHER_THING>`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please show an example of code?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: If you want to invest some time learning the reason behind this, check out [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44699/2288).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\textsc{<someother\_thing> }
\end{document}
```

[image: T1 output]