# csquotes: wrong kerning?

Tags: csquotes

I found that with `enquote` in the `csquotes` package, the closing double quote is too close to the last letter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\enquote{nature of}\\
``nature of''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this a known bug (which I don't have to report)? I use pdflatex in texlive 2016.

Comment: Thanks! If `csquotes` doesn't work correctly without `fontenc`, it should issue at least a warning, I suppose. Should I ask the creator of the package to consider it as an enhancement? (I prefer `enquote` to manual quotes because it handles nested quotes automatically.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not `csquotes` fault, it is a problem in the OT1-fonts: The kerning is missing if the quote symbol is entered directly and not through a ligature:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

of''
of\char"22
of\textquotedblright


\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
of''
of\char"11
of\textquotedblright
\end{document}
```

[image]

So this is another reason not to use OT1-encoding -- at least if you want to use the computer modern fonts (the lmodern fonts e.g. don't have this problem).

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Your and egreg's answers indicate that ot1enc.def has to be fixed. My next question then is why it's not done and why T1 is not default---If, on the other hand, there are valid reasons for OT1 to remain unfixed and default, then there should be warnings when some packages are broken under OT1.  It's like internal feud :-) The csquotes camp blames OT1 and the OT1 camp blames csquotes and the uniformed (me) is confused :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can fix what `ot1enc.def` does (which is, in my opinion, wrong):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% ot1enc.def has
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\textquotedblright}{OT1}{`\"}
% fix it
\DeclareTextCommand{\textquotedblright}{OT1}{''}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\enquote{nature of}\\
``nature of''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just load `fontenc` with the `T1` option (before `inputenc` in case you use it [[compare](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44699/37806)]).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \enquote{nature of}\\
  ``nature of''
\end{document}
```

[image]