# Newbie: Setting up a thesis template

Tags: templates, thesis

this might be a stupid question, but I am trying to use this template

```
% documentclass options:
% ngerman is needed for hyphenation if the thesis contains parts written in German
% BCOR is binding correction
% if you'd rather have a one sided thesis, add `onside' to the documentclass
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, english, ngerman]{scrbook}

% include all packages and define commands in setup.tex
\input{setup}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty} % no header and no page number
    % disable hyper links to remove warning "destination with same identifier"
    % this means within this section nothing can be referenced with a hyperlink
%    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    \include{chapters/0_0-titlepage}
    \pagestyle{plain} % remove chapter name from top, page number at the bottom
    \frontmatter  % roman page numbers
    \include{chapters/0_1-declaration}
    \include{chapters/0_2-abstract}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listofalgorithms
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}  % re-enable hyperlinking

    \mainmatter  % Arabic page numbers
    \include{chapters/1-introduction}
    \include{chapters/2-relatedwork}
    \include{chapters/3-background}
    \include{chapters/4-approach}
    \include{chapters/5-experiments}
    \include{chapters/6-conclusions}
    \include{chapters/7-acknowledgments}

    % bibliography is not in the table of contents per default, add it manually
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{bib/topic1,bib/topic2}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \mbox{}


\end{document}
```

and I keep getting an error asking where the setup.tex file is, now when I loo for it I have another `tex` file called `setup.tex` which is

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       package includes
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % font encoding is set up for pdflatex, for other environments see
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % 8-bit fonts, improves handling of hyphenations
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    % provides `old' commands for table of contents. Eases the ability to switch
    % between book and scrbook
    \usepackage{scrhack}


    % ------------------- layout, default -------------------
    % adjust the style of float's captions, separated from text to improve readabilty
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=colon, format=hang, textfont=singlespacing]{caption}
    \usepackage{chngcntr}  % continuous numbering of figures/tables over chapters
    \counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
    \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
    \counterwithout{table}{chapter}

    % Uncomment the following line if you switch from scrbook to book
    % and comment the setkomafont line
    %\usepackage{titlesec}  % remove "Chapter" from the chapter title
    %\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter}{2pc}{\huge}
    \setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}

    \usepackage{setspace}  % Line spacing
    \onehalfspacing
    % \doublespacing  % uncomment for double spacing, e.g. for annotations in correction

    % ------------------- functional, default-------------------
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % more colors
    \usepackage{array}  % custom format per column in table - needed on the title page
    \usepackage{graphicx}  % include graphics
    \usepackage{subfig}  % divide figure, e.g. 1(a), 1(b)...
    \usepackage{amsmath}  % |
    \usepackage{amsthm}   % | math, bmatrix etc
    \usepackage{amsfonts} % |
    \usepackage{calc}  % calculate within LaTeX
    \usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
                bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,breaklinks=false,
                pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}


    %==========================================
    % You might not need the following packages, I only included them as they
    % are needed for the example floats
    % ------------------- functional, custom -------------------
    \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{bm}  % bold greek variables (boldmath)
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % use: above left of, etc

    % Improves general appearance of the text
    \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true, kerning]{microtype}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       (re)new commands / settings
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % ----------------- referencing ----------------
    \newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\ref{#1})}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}

    % ------------------- colors -------------------
    \definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
    % Colors of the Albert Ludwigs University as in
    % https://www.zuv.uni-freiburg.de/service/cd/cd-manual/farbwelt
    \definecolor{UniBlue}{RGB}{0, 74, 153}
    \definecolor{UniRed}{RGB}{193, 0, 42}
    \definecolor{UniGrey}{RGB}{154, 155, 156}


    % ------------------- layout -------------------
    % prevents floating objects from being placed ahead of their section
    \let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}
    \let\mySubSection\subsection\renewcommand{\subsection}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySubSection}


    % ------------------- marker commands -------------------
    % ToDo command
    \newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{(TODO: #1)}}}
    \newcommand{\extend}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{darkgreen}{(EXTEND: #1)}}}
    % Lighter color to note down quick drafts
    \newcommand{\draft}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{(DRAFT: #1)}}}


    % ------------------- math formatting commands -------------------
    % define vectors to be bold instead of using an arrow
    \renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
    \newcommand{\mat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
    % tag equation with name
    \newcommand{\eqname}[1]{\tag*{#1}}


    % ------------------- pdf settings -------------------
    % ADAPT THIS
    \hypersetup{pdftitle={The great title!},
                pdfauthor={FirstName LastName},
                pdfsubject={Undergraduate thesis at the Albert Ludwig University of Freiburg},
                pdfkeywords={deep learning, awesome algorithm,  undergraduate thesis},
                pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}


    %==========================================
    % You might not need the following commands, I only included them as they
    % are needed for the example floats

    % ------------------- Tikz styles -------------------
    \tikzset{>=latex}  % arrow style


    % ------------------- algorithm ---------------------
    % Command to align comments in algorithm
    \newcommand{\alignedComment}[1]{\Comment{\parbox[t]{.35\linewidth}{#1}}}
    % define a foreach command in algorithms
    \algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{foreach}}
    \algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
```

but to be honest I don't really know what this means. I just want this template to run, and I don't know how to

Comment: You should not use templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Save the template code in a file, say, `main.tex`, located in a particular directory,

2- Save the secondary snippet in a file called `setup.tex` in the same directory,

3- Call `pdflatex`.