# Do I need utf8 inputenc when I am already using T1 fontenc?

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings

For German texts I use `T1 fontenc` so that the search option in my pdf preview can also find the umlauts.
When I count the number of words using `TeXcount`, it tells me that the text is encoded in `utf8`. Does that mean that I don't need `utf8 inputenc` at all when I use `T1 fontenc`?

Comment: If you are using a recent distribution, `inputenc` with a UTF8 encoding is built into the format, and therefore doesn't need to be loaded. But this is not because you loaded `fontenc`. The two packages do different things. See [fontenc vs inputenc](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/44694) for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: You said, that with a recent TeX distribution `utf8` is assumed: But if I use an English text without `T1 fontenc` or `utf8 inputenc`, `TeXcount` tells me that the text is encoded in `ascii`.

Comment: Perhaps TeXcount is just guessing based on the characters it finds. Your editor determines the encoding of your file, so it's UTF-8 independent of the language you write in for most editors these days, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: For a discussion of `fontenc` versus `inputenc`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44699/4427 that shows how the two packages address *different* issues. On the other hand, nowadays `inputenc` is only needed if one uses an input encoding different from UTF-8. Ask the maintainer of TeXcount to update to the current setup.

Comment: ASCII is also valid UTF-8. If your English text doesn’t use any characters that aren’t on a US keyboard, its UTF-8 encoding will be the same as its encoding in ASCII. But that’s also true of Latin-1 or CP1252, so a scan can’t tell which of those it was saved as.