# Why doesn't LaTeX hyphenate words containing accents, e.g. "développement"?

Tags: hyphenation, input-encodings

In this MWE, Latex doesn't hyphen the word "développement" and prefer to create a HUGE hbox.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}

% Title Page
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}
\section{Section} 
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{description}
 \item [Marhalie Toucse : ]  ingénieure de la plate-forme SORTATZ. Elle réalise 
 le développement du projet des tex écrit pour lipsum lagae legarc sgsi text text text text text text text text text. 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can manually add a hyphen using `\-` where you need. // Tu peux ajouter un hyphen manuellement avec `\-` à l'endroit de ton choix.

Comment: I know that but it's strange that Latex doesn't do it.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with italian babel with the word "generatori", which is quite popular by the way. So, instead of manually hyphen (which is always good, locally), I used `\hyphenation{ge-ne-ra-to-ri}` and this solved my problem.

Comment: With your code, I do not have this problem. There must be something else in your preamble that perturbates babel and/or french hyphenation. Other suggestion: if you write "ingénieur" without the final "e" (as should be, in my opinion), does it hyphenate?

Comment: The image I posted is the result of the compilation of the MWE I provided. Even if I write "ingénieur" it doesn't hyphenate. By the way ingénieure is the female form of "ingénieur".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TeX does not allow automatic hyphenation at accents which are constructed from two parts: as set up you are using the `OT1` encoding and this means that `é` is produced using a 'stand alone' acute accent and a normal `e`. Switching to the modern `T1` encoding means that a 'real' `é` is available, and hyphenation is possible. Indeed, there is a warning in the log with your demo saying

> ```
> Package frenchb.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.
> (frenchb.ldf)                Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble
> (frenchb.ldf)                of your document, on input line 14.
> ```

If you add the line suggested then hyphenation is possible (and occurs).

One way to check this is to

```
\showhyphens{développement}
```

which shows hyphenation positions in the log. Without `fontenc` you get

```
[] \OT1/lmr/m/n/12 d^^Seveloppement
```

where `^^` is the accent and notable there are no break points. In contrast, add `fontenc` with the `T1` encoding and you see

```
[] \T1/lmr/m/n/12 d�-ve-lop-pe-ment
```

with valid break points (pdfTeX is still 8-bit so can't show the `é` properly in the log!).

For more on this, see for example [Why words with accented characters can't be automatic hyphenated with the default OT1 enconding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725/why-words-with-accented-characters-cant-be-automatic-hyphenated-with-the-defaul) and [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc).

Comment: I always see that warning but I never known what does it mean. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user230137 do you mean `OT1 encoding should not be used for French`?  if so you're forgiven for not understanding it ... but it does give a solution to the problem on the next line: `Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble of your document` ... do that and the warning will go away and hyphenation will be more nearly accurate.

Comment: I use kile and I haven't seen `Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble of your document`.