# Natbib - \cite produces text out of margin

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

Is it possible to prevent citations from being shown out of the page margin?

Example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear}

\begin{filecontents}{bibl.bib}
  @book{book1,
    author = {Primeiro Ultimo},
    title = {Example without special characters},
    year = {2016}
  }

  @book{book2,
    author = {Primeiro \'Ultimo},
    title = {Example with accent},
    year = {2016}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb  \cite{book1}
  % hyphenated

  bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb  \cite{book2}
  % out of margin

  bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb \cite{book1}
  % out of margin

  bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb \cite{book2}
  % out of margin

  \bibliography{bibl}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to solve this by loading the packages `breakcites` and `cite`, but they did not help.

Thank you.

*I have also asked this [elsewhere](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=28467), but I haven't got any answers so far.*

Comment: The hyphenation issue is because your test document is using the `OT1` encoding, and accented words won't be hyphenated. See [Why doesn't LaTeX hyphenate words containing accents, e.g. "développement"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183808).

Comment: Is there any news here?