# Hyphenation of words with accents doesn't work

Tags: hyphenation, accents

Hyphenation of words with accents doesn't work. I'm writing my document in Portuguese so I have accents like '`~^ for some words but these words are not hyphenated. How do I solve this?

THIS WAS SOLVED BY: 
(1) updating my texlive installation.
(2) adding the lines

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to my document. Actually the last line is not necessary but the text font would be too ugly without it.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}` in your preamble?

Comment: And you'll want to be using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to allow hyphenation - see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc/677#677) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725/why-words-with-accented-characters-cant-be-automatic-hyphenated-with-the-defaul).

Comment: Both doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm writing my chapters in separated files? I mean: \chapter{Mecânica Elementar}
\input{mecanica_elementar}

Comment: no, splitting things into files with `input` should not make any difference. did you read the links and made sure none of the answers there help? if so, can you give a MWE for your specific case so we can test?

Comment: i posted my document.

Comment: If you don't post also `cenas` we can't test many things… Just  a lead: add `\usepackage{lmodern}`, for instance.

Comment: it's only text like "adiabática" nothing more. But this word is not hyphenated, all the other are.

Comment: @David There must be something you're not telling us, because the word "adiabática" gets hyphenated as expected in the following MWE: `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\begin{document}
adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática
adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática
adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática adiabática
\end{document}`

Comment: maybe i dont have this package \usepackage[portuguese]{babel} How do i install this?

Comment: @David The `babel` package should already be installed. Have you tried compiling the MWE in my previous comment? If you get no compilation error, then `babel` is already installed.

Comment: it gives me the error ! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The inability of TeX (and LaTeX, etc) to hyphenate words with accents -- *if* the accented words were constructed using accenting primitives and if the font encoding is the "original" or "old" TeX encoding -- has been known for a long time.

What to do? You should (a) if at all possible input the accented words directly, e.g., as `adiabática`, (b) use any font encoding other than OT1 (which, as you can probably guess, is the original font encoding method), and (c) load the `babel` or `polyglossia` packages with the appropriate language choices.

The MWE below was compiled using LuaLaTeX; if compiled under pdfLaTeX the first word would not get hyphenated. (That's a different shortcoming...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\setlength\textwidth{1mm} % to force the use of every possible hyphenation point

\begin{document}
\noindent
adiabática adiabática
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. this gives me the error ! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.

Comment: @David - *What exactly* gives rise to the error you report? It can't be either my MWE -- its output is shown above, and it compiles without error -- or the code you've posted (with the instruction `\input{cenas}` commented out, since I don't have that file, and with a right curly brace, `}`, inserted after `{autor`). I suggest you post a new query with an actual MWE that gives rise to the font-related problem you're encountering.

Comment: it was strictly your your code in a blank tex file.

Comment: @David -- What's your TeX distribution (TeXLive?, MikTeX? something else?) and vintage? Do you use pdfLaTeX or the (by now very old and obsolete) version of LaTeX that can generate only dvi files?

Comment: I dont know. I installed texmaker in ubuntu with apt-get. and i use pdflatex

Comment: @David - I don't know ubuntu, but it looks like your installation of TeXLive didn't complete correctly; at the very least, some font-related files are missing.

Comment: I just updated my textlive installation. Now it says: ! Package babel Error: Unknown option `portuguese'. Either you misspelled it

Comment: @David - Sorry to hear that your travails continue. The spelling `portuguese` should most certainly be recognized as a package option.

Comment: Now that i pdated my textlive version, adding the line \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} worked for me without the need to use \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}. Thanks to all for your help. Why do I have such an ugly font now? Is there anyway I can change that?

Comment: about my last question: That is also solved already: i just add the line: \usepackage{lmodern}. Thank you all