# How to insert pipe symbol in (La)TeX?

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

How to insert pipe symbol `|` in TeX (LaTeX)?

I have tried this sample with `pdflatex tmp.tex`

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\begin{document}
\textpipe
\end{document}
```

And it give `undefined control sequence` error

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/extsizes/extarticle.cls
Document Class: extarticle 1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/exscale.sty))
No file tmp.aux.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \textpipe
```

Comment: The link to the original SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487966/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-tex

Comment: Special case: with ltxdoc/l3doc/shortvrb + MakeShortVerb refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665617/250119

Comment: You can simply use /vert to add the Pipe

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The pipe symbol may be used directly in the input and will produce the desired output if you use T1 font encoding. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Pipe sign: |
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Compare these tables to see the difference between the two font encodings: [OT1 (Standard encoding)](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/ot1.htm) vs. [T1 (Cork encoding)](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm). The OT1 table doesn't contain the pipe symbol, but it can be found in the T1 table. It's position is 7C. With OT1 7C means a wide dash, that's why we get a wide dash instead of the pipe symbol in standard encoding.

See [Special LaTeX characters](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/fonts/symbols/) for some more information.

For using the command `\textpipe` loading a package like `tipa` or `t4phonet` is necessary.

Comment: Ah, another reason to use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. I've added this to another [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc/677#677), but could you explain why this happens, exactly? (Either here or at the post on texblog.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I've added links to the encoding tables and a brief explanation.

Comment: There's also a encoding table at https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf

Answer (score 45):

It is unnecessary to load any additional packages unless there are other reasons to do so. Mathmode provides alternative symbols `$\vert$` for a vertical pipe and `$\Vert$` for a double pipe. These appear to be independent of encoding. Actually as a math symbol `$|$` appears also to be encoding independent.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should be added anyway, because it fixes a  lot of font-related problems.

Comment: I wasn't aware of $\vert$. I've been using $\mid$, which looks identical to me.

Comment: When I used this method my word exceeds the page width. How can I avoid that? My two words are \texttt{--}genotyping\_mode GENOTYPE\_GIVEN\_ALLELES.

Comment: The difference between $\mid$ and $\vert$ appears to be spacing around the symbol, which $\mid$ has and $\vert$ doesn't. Also, $|$ lacks spacing around it. Unfortunately, using $\bigg$ on $\mid$ results in an error.

Answer (score 23):

I would recommend using the command `\textbar`, since this does not require you to use different encoding or additional packages.  For me this was a much better solution, as I was already committed to `usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.  Also, I am using a system that puts UTF-8 data into LaTeX templates (escaping special characters), and this system cannot rely on any additional packages (other than UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: I am not sure if you know the difference between _input_ encoding and _font_ encoding. Maybe the following question is interesting for you:    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc

Comment: Yes @matth, you are of course right.  I guess when reading this question my eyes glazed over {fontenc} and I read in incorrectly.

Comment: `\texttt{A\textbar{}B}` produces homogeneous formatting.

Comment: The `{}` is redundant and kind of bad practice as well (it breaks kerning). Just do `\texttt{A\textbar B}`.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note: MikTeX supports using pipes in \input if you supply the flag -enable-pipes. This is useful for calling external programs directly from your document.

Here is an example of getting input from Octave and a listing of the document files:

```
%& -enable-pipes
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\octave[2][]{%
   \input"|octave -qf --eval 'format #1;disp(#2)'"
}

\begin{document}

Foo $\pi \approx \octave{pi}$ bar.
\begin{align}
   \pi           &\approx \octave[long]{pi} \\
   \sqrt 2       &\approx \octave[short]{sqrt(2)} \\
   \pi\exp(3\pi) &\approx \octave[short g]{pi*exp(3*pi)}
\end{align}

{\obeylines
List of files:
\input"|ls -l \jobname.*"
}

\end{document}
```

I am using MikTeX on a Linux system. If you are running windows you must make changes to the example accordingly.

Comment: I've recently been told that this is also supported in TeX Live with `-shell-escape`.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with the original question `:)`