# Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (¡) or question mark (¿)?

Tags: symbols, punctuation, font-encodings

When typing `<` or `>` in LaTeX and compiling with `pdflatex`, the less than and greater than symbols appear at upside down exclamation points. I'm not in math mode.

Comment: using it in a regression results table in a paper.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: "This example holds true for all cases where n >= 3".

Comment: see also [beramono and texttt : angle brackets show as inverted exclamation mark and inverted question mark symbols (upside-down signs, like in spanish)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292189/579) for a font-specific answer with bera mono

Comment: Worth noting that you can also use modern OpenType or TrueType fonts, in either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, with the `fontspec` package. In this case, you do not want to load the T1 encoding. The encodings will already be set up properly.

Comment: Similar question for `|`: [font encodings - How to insert pipe symbol in (La)TeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-latex/1775#1775) ■ question explaining the historical reason for this oddity: [What is the reason behind why > and < don't display properly without T1 font encoding? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222448/what-is-the-reason-behind-why-and-dont-display-properly-without-t1-font-enc)

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Geoffs tip with `\textless` and `\textgreater` will work well for you. However, you could type these symbols < and > directly in your editor and they would be correctly printed if you use the recommended font encoding, Cork resp. T1:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Have a look at the [T1 encoding table](https://web.archive.org/web/20211201101310/http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm), search for the symbols < and >. Afterwards, open the [OT1 encoding table](https://web.archive.org/web/20211025142237/http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/ot1.htm), which is the default. At the two corresponding places you will find the upside down exclamation resp. quotation mark. That should explain it.

For further reasons, why you should use T1 encoding, have a look at this question: [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc)

You should use a font supporting T1. For instance use the very good Latin Modern font, derived from the standard fonts:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Or install the [`cm-super`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) package which provides the standard Computer Modern fonts with T1 support.

Comment: Further reading: [Latin Modern vs cm-super?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390)

Comment: will this screw up any other part of the document?

Comment: @HaoSun It's an improvement. If something would change that you don't desire, it can be fixed. If you don't want any change, just don't change.

Comment: The link "T1 encoding table" is stale.

Comment: Replaced the stale links with archive.org versions.

Answer (score 144):

Use `\textless` and `\textgreater`.

Comment: unless they are part of a math expression, in which case they should be between dollar signs or \\( ... \\) along with the rest of the math expression.

Answer (score 26):

What I usually do is just enter mathmode to type them, e.g. `This object is $<$ that object`.

Comment: That is generally considered poor style. You should just write out "This object is less than that object." Occasionally, you'll see "foo is <0." This looks bad.

Comment: That's definitely true. However, if you're using LaTeX to organize your thoughts (as i often do), 'good style' equates to 'will I understand what I wrote if I come back and look at it in a week'!

Comment: @TH.: I agree with you. My experiency tells me too that text and math code should not be mixed up. Good style would be either writing "The variable $foo$ is less than zero." (as you mentioned) or "The variable $foo$ satisfies the relation/condition $foo<0$.", which would probably suit your application. Good style means also to define variables at the first use.

Comment: @strpeter While mentioning style, it is worth noting that `variable $foo$` is not good style either: it refers to the product of `$f$`, `$o$`, and `$o$`.  You mean `variable $\mathit{foo}$`.

Comment: OK, I was not typing it correct in the sense of the variable as I focused on the operator. You're right - use your preferred version `$\mathit{foo}<0$`, `$\mathrm{foo}<0$`, `$\mathbf{foo}<0$`, or whatever variable. ;)

Comment: Ah no way. It's so much easier to read when there are symbols. Sure it might be bad style but I always put readability first.

Comment: FWIW: I also use > to denote menu navigation  - e.g., "File > Examples > Basics > blinkenlights.ino."

Answer (score 0):

This very old question appeared when I searched for something else. Looking at the old answers, I see that `T1` encoding is recommended, when compiling with `pdflatex`. But a many things have happened since then.

If at all possible, compile with a utf-8 aware engine such as `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`. You do not need to know any Lua code (apparently, many potential users have the incorrect belief that Lua programming is needed). The required Lua code is built-in, and invisible to the end user. Of course, if you do know Lua, you can add more.

If compiling with `lualatex`, your input text must be utf-8 encoded. Nowadays, that is almost certainly true. You must use the `fontspec` package. After the document class, `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Then use its commands, such as `\setmainfont`, to manipulate fonts. Be sure to select OpenType (or TrueType) fonts. In some cases `fontspec` can handle the older Type1 fonts, but that is the wrong way to do it.

In text mode, using `lualatex`, when I type `<` or `>`, that is what I get. If I use a character map to insert an inverted exclamation or question mark, that is what I get. There are also some LaTeX macros for that, but copy/paste from a character map has the advantage that your source text will appear correct,
without LaTeX code there.

Comment: If somebody asks for help in flying a hot-air balloon, do you tell them to use an airplane?

Comment: @egreg No, but if someone in the year 1912 asked for help with a hot air baloon, I would mention that in the intervening time, the airplane was invented. The OP was 13 years ago. Unfortunately, SE retains old questions, with old solutions, and they are often highly ranked. So persons searching for something might be unaware of possibilities that were not often discussed, years ago.