# Include < (fewer than) and > (greater than) inequality symbols

Tags: symbols

I'd like to include the `<` and `>` symbols into my document. First I tried to just type it in. But after generating the document I saw only an inverted ? instead of the > symbol.

That's why I looked at this [LaTeX Math Symbols](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html)  document and I saw that it should work that way. Nevertheless I tried to solve the problem by using the `verbatim` command:

```
\begin{verbatim}>\end{verbatim}
```

Now it works, but the problem is that the `verbatim` command seems to include a linebreak and that's why the `>` symbol now is in the wrong line.

How can I solve that?

Comment: In General: for single verbatim character use `\verb+>+`. See also the package *shortvrb*. However for `<` and `>` the macros you mention in your answer are better.

Comment: So I guess we should close this as a duplicate of [Less than symbol (<) appears as upside down](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/less-than-symbol-appears-as-upside-down)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To quote from the [Comprehensive Symbols List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (which has these symbols listed as ”frequently requested”):

> The characters “<”, “>”, and “|” do
>   work as expected in math mode,
>   although they produce, respectively,
>   “¡”, “¿”, and “—” in text mode when
>   using the OT1 font encoding. 
>   The following are some alternatives for
>   typesetting “<”, “>”, and “|”:
>
> - Specify a document font encoding other
>     than OT1 (as described on page 8).
> - Use the appropriate symbol commands
>     from Table 2 on page 9, viz.
>     `\textless`, `\textgreater`, and `\textbar`.
> - Enter the symbols in math mode
>     instead of text mode, i.e., `$<$`, `$>$`,
>     and `$|$`.
>
> Note that for typesetting
>   metavariables many people prefer
>   `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` to
>   `\textless` and `\textgreater`; i.e., “〈filename〉” instead of “<filename>”.

From page 8 (with strong recommendations that you should use this):

> One note that appears a few times in
>   this document, particularly in Section
>   2, indicates that certain symbols do
>   not exist in the OT1 font encoding
>   (Donald Knuth’s original, 7-bit font
>   encoding, which is the default font
>   encoding for LaTeX) and that you
>   should use `fontenc` to select a
>   different encoding, such as T1 (a
>   common 8-bit font encoding). That
>   means that you should put
>   “`\usepackage[ encoding ]{fontenc}`” in
>   your document’s preamble, where
>   `encoding` is, e.g., `T1` or `LY1`. To limit
>   the change in font encoding to the
>   current group, use “`\fontencoding{ encoding }\selectfont`”.

As Will notes in the comments, a good solution to this is to put

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

into your preamble.

Alternatively, using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the `fontspec` package also makes these symbols (and many more) work correctly.

Comment: Strong suggestion to fix this problem once and for all based on that quote: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` `\usepackage{lmodern}` (or other font package)

Comment: Be warned that if this is a submission for a scientific journal/conference and you change the font you might get into trouble.

Answer (score 14):

With T1 encoding you could use both symbols directly within your text, without math mode or macros:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

These symbols are not available in standard encoding and font. For further information have a look at [Less than symbol (<) appears as upside down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/less-than-symbol-appears-as-upside-down).

Answer (score 10):

Using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) I found the correct symbol:

```
\textgreater

\textless
```

Comment: I'm just seeing that Detexify needs help (http://detexify.posterous.com/detexify-needs-help) to run its server. I already made the start with 10 bugs.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to get too verbose, using math mode is simple: `$>$ $<$`