# How can I have the three source-code symbols _ < > produce themselves (_ < >) in the typeset output by default?

Tags: characters

I use LaTeX to take quick notes about my programming work.  I have a couple of frustrations:

- I need to use underscore a lot because of variables named with underscores.  However, I have to escape each one of them "`\_`", thus making my notes less readable on the markup side.
- I commonly want to use "`<`" and "`>`" symbols - why oh why are the default representations of these symbols "`¿`" and "`¡`"?

Is there anyway I can alter LaTeX so that "_", "<", and ">" literally typeset as "_", "<", and ">"?

Comment: For your second question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10300/include-and-symbol/10303#10303

Comment: First question is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are canonical ways to fix both of these problems. For the underscore:

```
\usepackage{underscore}
```

For the rendering of `<` and `>`:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: wow - that was simple

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, since the last month `\nonknuthmode` is default in ConTeXt. What this means is `_`, `^`, and `&` work in text mode. So, the following is a valid input:

```
\starttext
under_score car^et & ampersand work in text mode, and have their 
usual meaning in math mode
\startformula
  x_a^b = \cases{ 0 & a < b \cr 1 & a \ge b }
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Comment: Interesting - this is more-or-less the long-term LaTEX3 plan too. I'll probably take a look at the appropriate ConTeXt code at some stage.

Answer (score 8):

An obligatory ConTeXt answer (plus Aditya's `:)`), using `\asciimode` will make all special characters "un-special" except `\`, `{` and `}`:

```
\starttext
\asciimode
$ % & _ # ^ ~ | < >
\{ \} \backslash
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on (I do that a lot, lately) Roflcoptr suggestion of using `\textgreater` and `\textless`, you can do

```
\catcode`\<\active
\catcode`\>\active
\let<\textgreater
\let>\textless
\catcode`\_\active
\let_\_
```

I am assuming that you are not using `_` in maths as well. Otherwise, try

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\~`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~{\ifmmode\expandafter_\else\expandafter\_\fi}}
\catcode`\_\active
```

instead of `\catcode... \let_\_`. EDIT: note the different placement of `\catcode...`.

Comment: Using \mathcode"8000 (=‘math active’) is a more robust way to do this sort of thing. (See the internals of underscore.sty.) Although I'm not aware of any specific problems with the approach you've taken (perhaps it's less efficient, is all?).

Comment: This will probably have the same problem as `underscore`, where `\includegraphics{filename_with_underscore}` won't work.