# Correctly typesetting words surrounded by double underscores?

Tags: typewriter

Forgive me if the answer to this is obvious, I've just begun working with LaTex and I've had no luck with Google.

I'm working on learning LaTeX, and as part of my practice I'm rewriting a guide on special methods in Python in LaTeX. As you might know, Python's special methods take on the form `__methodname__`. This causes problems when I try to generate a PDF from my .tex source file using pdflatex. How can I make LaTeX ignore the double underscores, or otherwise make my output correct?

In case it might help, here's a sample of what I'm trying to typeset:

```
 e.g. \texttt{__init__} or \texttt{__lt__}
```

Which I want to look like "e.g. `__init__` or `__lt__`".

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/how-can-i-fix-my-most-common-latex-complaints help?

Comment: @Caramdir somewhat. `\usepackage{underscore}` makes everything generate without error, but the underscores have a space between them, which looks ugly :(

Comment: When you are typesetting Python computer code it is important to show that it is two distinct underscores. "Ugly" is not the issue here, but clarity.

Comment: @Danie the entire Python documentation (including that which is set with TeX) does not show two distinct underscores. It's fairly easy to distinguish between `_` and `__` especially in context.

Comment: It does not mean that the Python docs use good practices. I have many years of trying to teach engineering students programming and I can guarantee you, if there are ambiguities, it will cause problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\texttt{\_\_init\_\_}` or `\verb+__init__+` or with the inline options of the `listings` package

```
\makeatletter
% Ensure that the minus sign is the "-" character in listings
% for cut and paste operations from pdf docs
\newcommand*\verbfont{%
    \normalfont\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font\m@ne\@noligs}
\makeatother

\lstset{language         =Python,
        showstringspaces =false,
        keepspaces       =true,
        basicstyle       = \raggedright\verbfont\small\selectfont}

\newcommand\li{%
    \lstinline[basicstyle = \verbfont\raggedright]}
```

Then you can use `\li{__init__}`

Comment: Is there any advantage to any particular approach? `\verb!__init__!` seems easiest, but does it have some limitations?

Comment: @Rafe  `\verb` can not be used in macro arguments such as `\caption`, etc.  If it is a document about computer code go the `listings` way. It also gives a verbatim type environment for code listings with coloring and many other options.

Comment: @Rafe: If you go for `\verb` note that there is the `shortvrb` package which allows you to say `\MakeShortVerb{\|}` and then `|__init__|` is enough. Works with any other character like `!` as well.