# Define an "escape underscore" environment

Tags: macros, formatting, environments

I am writing a text document in LaTeX where I need a lot a words with underscores: `foo_bar_1`, `more_bar_2_long_expression_3`.

I know about the `underscore` package, but for some reason the `[strings]` option doesn't work for me (I get e.g. `Extra \endcsname. ...oncluding Chapter~\ref{ch:summary_outlook}`).

So my idea would be to define a new command or environment

```
\newcommand{escunderscore}[1]{...}
```

in which basically `_` would be replaced by `\_`, so that I then can write `\escunderscore{foo_bar_1}` in my text whenever I need underscores. Is this possible and how do I do this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/how-can-i-fix-my-most-common-latex-complaints

Comment: Looks like a dupe of the question Martin has linked to.

Comment: I think you'd be better off if you fix the broken `strings` option (it worked fine for me in a quick test). Wrapping words with underscores in an `\esc_underscore` command is not really more convenient or readable than manually escaping the underscores. Perhaps ask a new question about the `[strings]underscore` issue including a minimal example that reproduces your problem

Comment: The underscore package {without any special `strings` option}seems to work just fine for me, so not exactly sure what the problem

Comment: @Martin, @Joseph: If I understand correctly, the answer to the linked question is to use the `underscore` package, which doesn't work for fuenfundachtzig, so it's not really a duplicate.

Comment: @Peter: `underscore` without extra options works for you in `\ref` commands that include underscores?

Comment: @Jake: You're right that fixing this package would be the better solution, but I was looking for a quick fix. Personally I find `\trigger{EF_j75_a4tc_EFFS_jetNoEF_EFxe20_noMu}` easier to read than `EF\_j75\_a4tc\_EFFS\_jetNoEF\_EFxe20\_noMu`.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: Fair point, although that particular example seems hard to read to me regardless of whether the underscores are escaped or not =)

Comment: Remark, in your "MWE" you missed a backslash before the command name, see this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29463/250119

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do even better: say

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\catcode`\_=12
```

in your preamble and you'll be allowed to use the underscore as a printable character anywhere (requires a T1-encoded font, so the first line). For subscripts you can then use `\sb`.

A command for temporary escaping the underscore can be the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\escapeus}{\begingroup\@makeother\_\@escapeus}
\newcommand*{\@escapeus}[1]{#1\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

that, however, will not be usable in the argument of any command, because of the change in the category code (still requires a T1-encoded font).

If T1-encoded fonts are not available, something more complicated is needed:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\escapeus}{\begingroup\@activeus\@escapeus}
\newcommand*{\@escapeus}[1]{#1\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}
\makeatother
```

Again, the `\escapeus` command cannot be used as the argument of another command. If you really need it there's a way:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\escapeus}[1]{%
  \begingroup\@activeus\scantokens{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, also. This is exactly the solution I was looking for. The underscore package was too aggressive for my purposes: It  escapes things like `\label{tag_with_underscores}`, `\input{file_with_underscores}` and `|short_verbatim_with_underscore|`. A command that lets me have control of the process is perfect.

Comment: The last solution also works in `caption` etc.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Yes, it should, since it delays until the very last minute the interpretation of `_`.

Comment: @egreg: I used your last solution and together with @DavidCarlisle answer (http://is.gd/FOv6dA) it works very well. However, I tried to understand the magic for some time now and I fail. Can you please add some explanations? In particular, the order of grouping and the re-definition of `_`.

Comment: @Dror There's nothing special: the main command just calls `\@activeus` and then uses `\scantokens` so the argument will be reprocessed based on the current catcodes (where `_` is active). The second part is the activation code: `_` is made active and defined to be equivalent to `\_`.

Comment: Why the second part has the form `\begingroup ... { \endgroup .. }`? I thought groups have to be balanced.

Comment: @Dror They *are* balanced. `;-)` The tokens in the argument to `\lowercase` are just subject to lowercasing and then reinserted without being interpreted. This is a trick to get an active `_` without the need of explicitly activating it and avoids a global definition.

Answer (score 16):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\UScore{\urlstyle{rm}}
\begin{document}

foo \UScore{foo_bar_1} bar

\end{document}
```