# Breaking links and escaping characters in bibliographies with backlinks and ocgcolorlinks set

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, urls, back-referencing, ocg

I have the following situation: I have to use the `ocgcolorlinks` option in `hyperref`, so that links are not broken. So I had the idea to set each char as a link with `\href`. After putting some code together and understanding only half of what I was doing, I arrived with a solution that worked: both the linking as well as issues with escaping the special characters in the URLs with catcode.

Unfortunately, the intention was to mainly use it in the bibliography, and when `backref` and `pagebackref` is used in `hyperref`, some macros or something are redefined so that the escaping again does not work there. I was not able to fix this.

In the following you find a minimal example using my ugly hack:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks,breaklinks=true,backref=page,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

%adapted from http://tex-and-stuff.blogspot.com/2011/03/counting-number-of-characters-in-tex_10.html
\newcommand{\targetlink}{}
\def\gobblechar{\let\char= }
\newcount\charcount
\def\countunlessnil{%
  \ifx\char\nil \let\next=\relax%
  \else%
    \let\next=\auxcountchar%
    \advance\charcount by 1%
  \fi\next
}%
\def\assignthencheck{\afterassignment\checknil\gobblechar}
\def\checknil{%
  \ifx\char\nil%
     \let\next=\relax%
  \else%
     \oldhref{\targetlink}{\char}\allowbreak\let\next=\assignthencheck% %%this is the place where each char is processed
  \fi%
  \next%
}
\let\oldhref\href%
%inspired of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-actinarg
\def\href#1{
    \renewcommand{\targetlink}{#1}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\&=12
\catcode`\~=12
\xhref
}
\def\xhref#1{
    \assignthencheck #1\nil%
    \endgroup
}%
\def\url{%
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\&=12
\catcode`\~=12
\xurl
}%
\def\xurl#1{
    \renewcommand{\targetlink}{#1}%
    \assignthencheck #1\nil%
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}
\url{http://a_b/c&d/~e}
\href{http://a_b/c&d/~e}{http://a_b/c&d/~e}
$\begin{array}{cc}s&ep\end{array}up_down$no~tilde

\bibliographystyle{diss1}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[t]{test}
\newblock
\url{http://a_b/c&d/~e} %error here
\href{http://a_b/c&d/~e}{http://a_b/c&d/~e} %error here
$\begin{array}{cc}s&ep\end{array}up_down$no~tilde
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The output should then be two times:

```
 http://a_b/c&d/~e http://a_b/c&d/~e s epdownno tilde
```

Any idea what is happening and how I can fix it? Note that escaping the characters in the source in not really an option since I get it from a database and it would also set the links incorrectly.

Any other suggestions for cleaning the code or inserting `\allowbreak` only at non-letters/spaces are also welcome.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I almost forgot why I wrote this whole code. Your solution works perfectly. And from your explanation, it seems to do this because it does it how it should be done in pdf! Thanks. The only thing I noticed is that sometimes the font gets a little bit "ugly", like rastered. This only happened on my Windows machine and only on the screen, not in Linux. So I suppose it has something to do with installed fonts or something?! One more note, the links are only printed not in color if you use the right viewer. Okular under Linux does not interpret the content groups correctly, it s

Comment: Glad I could help.  If the answer works for you, please consider accepting the answer.  (Also, in the future if you comment directly on the answer, rather than on your own question, the answer's author will be notified of your comment.)  As for the "slightly ugly" rendering on Windows, I occasionally see that myself -- I think it's because fonts and filled paths are antialiased slightly differently, so you'll see a "fringe" of the uncolored text underneath the colored OCG content.  When I figure out more PDf commands, I'll revise the code below...

Answer (score 26):

***Edited 7/17/12 to add a workaround for XeLaTeX's lack of `\pdfliteral`***

***Edited 8/1/12 to consistently handle XeLaTeX's different location of the origin***

I've been working on an alternate approach to ocgcolorlinks that doesn't prevent line breaks in the set text.  And it also doesn't have to do any trickery to redefine macros, change catcodes, or even typeset the text twice.  (NOTE: I think I've emailed the correct maintainers of `hyperref` to see if this solution useful to them, but haven't heard back; in the meantime I'm posting it if it helps other people.)  Since I think your question is asking, "Is there a fairly robust way to enable line-breaks in `ocgcolorlinks` while preserving odd characters and macros?", I'll answer that rather than try to debug catcode and macro redefinitions.  The approach will work exactly for anything that `\url` could handle already.

The code below relies on a quirk of the meaning of Optional Content Groups in PDFs: while color-changing operations will occur regardless of whether the OCG is enabled or not, graphics operations like filling a path are conditional.  And, PDFs have a mode where text is used to set the clipping path, rather than to render as actual text.  The following code redefines a `hyperref` internal function, and produces line-breakable optional-colored hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=2in,paperwidth=2in,margin=0.25in}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newlength{\temp@x}%
    \newlength{\temp@y}%
    \newlength{\temp@w}%
    \newlength{\temp@h}%
    \def\my@coords#1#2#3#4{%
      \setlength{\temp@x}{#1}%
      \setlength{\temp@y}{#2}%
      \setlength{\temp@w}{#3}%
      \setlength{\temp@h}{#4}%
      \adjustlengths{}%
      \my@pdfliteral{\strip@pt\temp@x\space\strip@pt\temp@y\space\strip@pt\temp@w\space\strip@pt\temp@h\space re}}%
    \ifpdf
      \typeout{In PDF mode}%
      \def\my@pdfliteral#1{\pdfliteral page{#1}}% I don't know why % this command...
      \def\adjustlengths{}%
    \fi
    \ifxetex
      \def\my@pdfliteral #1{\special{pdf: literal direct #1}}% isn't equivalent to this one
      \def\adjustlengths{\setlength{\temp@h}{-\temp@h}\addtolength{\temp@y}{1in}\addtolength{\temp@x}{-1in}}%
    \fi%
    \def\Hy@colorlink#1{%
      \begingroup
        \ifHy@ocgcolorlinks
          \def\Hy@ocgcolor{#1}%
          \my@pdfliteral{q}%
          \my@pdfliteral{7 Tr}% Set text mode to clipping-only
        \else
          \HyColor@UseColor#1%
        \fi
    }%
    \def\Hy@endcolorlink{%
      \ifHy@ocgcolorlinks%
        \my@pdfliteral{/OC/OCPrint BDC}%
        \my@coords{0pt}{0pt}{\pdfpagewidth}{\pdfpageheight}%
        \my@pdfliteral{F}% Fill clipping path (the url's text) with
                           % current color
        %
        \my@pdfliteral{EMC/OC/OCView BDC}%
        \begingroup%
          \expandafter\HyColor@UseColor\Hy@ocgcolor%
          \my@coords{0pt}{0pt}{\pdfpagewidth}{\pdfpageheight}%
          \my@pdfliteral{F}% Fill clipping path (the url's text)
                             % with \Hy@ocgcolor
        \endgroup%
        \my@pdfliteral{EMC}%
        \my@pdfliteral{0 Tr}% Reset text to normal mode
        \my@pdfliteral{Q}%
      \fi
      \endgroup
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text before a long url that can break at hyphens, followed by the url itself
\url{http://long-url-that-can-break.com}, then a little bit more
text after that lengthy url\dots
\end{document}
```

It renders text into the clipping path, then fills the clipping path with the current (normal text) color.  Then, inside the `OCView` content group, it changes the color to `\Hy@ocgcolor` and fills the clipping path a second time.  The net result is colored text on screen, and normal text in the printout.  The text is even still selectable as text, and can be copied & pasted out of the document :)

Two caveats:

1. If you create a hyperlink with *no* text in it, then the entire page will be filled with `\Hy@ocgcolor`, because the default clipping path is the entire page until you've added at least one character's worth of paths into it...  I tried using the `W n` PDF operators to create a new clip path, but that failed; if anyone knows why, improvements are welcome.
2. Do not let the url straddle a page break, or else the second page will again be filled with `\Hy@ocgcolor`, because the second half of the command (that resets the clipping mode and fills the clipping path) doesn't run until the second page.  But since the fill command occurs on the second page, and none of the clipping path does, that whole page fills...  I tried using the various `AtBeginPage`-like hooks to clean up and resume the clip path, but they didn't run at the correct times.  Again, any expert advice is welcome.

Comment: This code works great in pdflatex, while it gives an error in xelatex. Could you please explain what can be done to get rid of it? ! Undefined control sequence.
\Hy@colorlink ...def \Hy@ocgcolor {#1}\pdfliteral page{q}\pdfliteral page{7 ...
l.46 \url{http://long-url-that-can-break.com} , then a little bit more
? Process interrupted by user

Comment: @rowman, xelatex doesn't define `\pdfliteral`, but it still does have `\special`, so I tweaked the code above to use that if necessary.  Does this new version work for you?  (It worked when I tried it, but I don't really know how PDF specials work, so I'm dubious of its robustness.)

Comment: Please convert this also to comment. thanks @Ben, The code works perfectly to break the lines but another problem. The link disappears upon printing.

Comment: @rowman, that's the point... how could you click on a printed-out hyperlink, anyway? :)  (That's the same behavior as the original boxed links, which don't print the boxes.)  If all you want is colored links, both in print and on screen, I think there's an option for that (`colorlinks`, maybe? dunno)

Comment: What I need is colored links on screen and black links on paper. The problem is that using your code the url prints black if compiled with pdflatex which is good but it's white using xelatex !

Comment: @rowman, that's odd...  I'll see if I can figure it out, but the PDF commands I used ought to Just Work.

Comment: @rowman, I think I fixed it, at least, it works for me with XeLaTeX and Acroread -- try again?

Comment: @BenLerner -- rowman says it works perfectly, and offers his thanks. In the future, please ask a mod to help you invite this user to chat.

Comment: @BenLerner, can I encourage you to package this up & upload it to CTAN?

Comment: Thanks for this fix! It really saved the day. For the record, `pgfplots`' `\label`/`\ref` mechanism is susceptible to caveat 1.

Comment: @BenLerner have you had any luck contacting the hyperref maintainers? Or have you turned the code into a package and uploaded it to CTAN? Thanks

Comment: I haven't touched this code in years ;-)  I tried emailing the hyperref maintainers (Heiko and Sebastian) in February 2012, but never heard back from either of them.  I might've gotten the wrong email addresses.  Perhaps mentioning @HeikoOberdiek might flag this answer to his attention?

Answer (score 12):

B. Lerner's method suggested here served as the basis for re-implementing `hyperrefs`'s `ocgcolorlinks` option in the **`ocgx2`** package, v0.24 [2017/03/30]. Also, issues 1 (**empty link texts**) and 2 (**page breaks**) could be resolved. If desired, links can be [↗nested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361422).

> ```
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
> ```

Example (open on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58de39fd21e27de5279580cd))

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}\raggedright\huge
Empty links $\Rightarrow$\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47267}{\quad}$\Leftarrow$ don't do any harm.\\[1ex]

Text before a long url that can break at hyphens, followed by the url itself: \url{http://long-url-that-wraps-around-line-breaks-and-page-breaks-long-url-that-wraps-around-line-breaks-and-page-breaks-long-url-that-wraps-around-line-breaks-and-page-breaks.com}, then a little bit more
text after that lengthy url\dots
\end{document}
```