# How to carry long text of \href to the next line while ocgcolorlinks is present?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, links, ocg

This simplest code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \href{"some URL"}{"long text"}
\end{document}
```

by compiling with **pdflatex** puts the `"long text"` in one line, i.e. with overfull of the line. When the option `ocgcolorlinks` of the `hyperref` package is omitted, the text is normally carried over to the next lines.

My question: How can I force the text to be carried over to the next lines with `ocgcolorlinks` present?

Comment: Related: [Breaking links and escaping characters in bibliographies with backlinks and ocgcolorlinks set](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47267/breaking-links-and-escaping-characters-in-bibliographies-with-backlinks-and-ocgc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option `ocgcolorlinks` does not support links that can be broken across lines. From `hyperref`'s README:

> - Main disadvantage: Links cannot be broken across lines.
>     PDF reference 1.7: 4.10.2 "Making Graphical Content Optional":
>       Graphics state operations, such as setting the color, ...,
>       are still applied.
>     Therefore the link text is put in a box and set twice, with and
>     without color.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}[2017/03/30]
> ```

Package **`ocgx2`**, as of version **0.24**, re-implements the **`ocgcolorlinks`** option of **`hyperref`**, based on [B. Lerner's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47309) with some refinements:

Besides OCG colour links that wrap around line breaks, also wrapping at **page breaks** and **nested** hyperlinks are supported (only pdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, as XeTeX does not support nested links at all), and the issue with **empty link text** has been resolved.

---

Example code (open on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58dd082421e27de527953f3b)):

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}[2017/03/30]

\usepackage{mwe,graphicx}

\begin{document}\raggedright\huge
  Empty links $\Rightarrow$\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{\qquad}$\Leftarrow$ don't flood the page with link colour.\\[2ex]

  Visit \href{https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2}{ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 \hypersetup{urlcolor=red}\href{https://ctan.org}{on CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN CTAN} ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2 ocgx2}!\\[2ex]

  {
    \normalsize Graphical content, if mixed with text inside the link text, must be protected by enclosing in \verb+\ocglinkprotect{...}+:\\[1ex]
  }

  Visit \href{https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe}{this fancy \ocglinkprotect{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}} on CTAN!}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very promising solution, but for me, when I print preview your ShareLaTeX example in Evince and Okular they still look colored. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not with the PDF. It is  Evince and Okular which do not acknowledge the printing-settings associated with the PDF layers (OCGs) that contain the viewer and printer versions of the links. If you have time, you could file a bug report to Okular/Evince developers. The same also happens with the original `ocgcolorlinks` option of `hyperref` as well as with B. Lerners code.

Comment: I see, thank you. I will devote some time on this.

Comment: More specifically, it is the `/Usage<</Print<</PrintState/OFF>> >>` entry in the OCG object for viewing and `/Usage<</Print<</PrintState/ON>> >>` in the OCG object for printing that are not evaluated by Evince/Okular.

Comment: Until it gets implemented in Evince/Okular, I found that it works in Chromium/Chrome, which have their own pdf reader.

Comment: Good news! I've never dared testing this in a web browser :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57059/discussion-between-alexg-and-makish).

Comment: What is the purpose of the `[2017/03/30]` option?

Comment: It spits out a warning if you try to load an older version of the package sty file. (in case your TeX installation is not up to date)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer on TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47309/5699) by Ben Lerner allows automatic line breaking when `ocgcolorlinks` is in use, with a hack:

> The code […] relies on a quirk of the meaning of Optional Content Groups in PDFs: while color-changing operations will occur regardless of whether the OCG is enabled or not, graphics operations like filling a path are conditional. And, PDFs have a mode where text is used to set the clipping path, rather than to render as actual text

The mechanism has a few issues, notably with empty text and page breaks. The former can likely be auto-detected by typesetting the text in a box first and checking whether it is empty or not. The latter might be solvable using tricks from [Reacting to a page break in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252335/5699).

In principle, it would also be possible to write a macro which breaks down the text into individual words (or characters, as [the OP (LittleLatexNoTex) of that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47267/5699) tried to do), and wraps each one on a distinct `\href{url}{word}`. Doing so is non-trivial when macros are used in the text, however, as the LittleLatexNoTex pointed out.

Comment: This feature has been made available through the `ocgx2` package, v0.24 [2017/03/30].