# Bibliography and Jabref

Tags: biblatex

[image]

I have some problems with the bibliography of my thesis and Jabref. 
I don't understand why some URL or DOI go out the borders... Can you help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=phys,biblabel=brackets,natbib=true,sorting=none,url=true,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{tesi.bib}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{8000}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with  poor old JabRef… Simply, LaTeX, by default, cannot hyphenate url's anywhere. You have to customise the rules for hyphenating url's. Other possibility, asking for urls to start a new line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... How can I do that? And why some links cannot hyphenate and others do?

Comment: By default it breaks urls at some well-defined points, in particular not after a digit. Do you  use `biblatex`?

Comment: Yes, biblatex and Jabref

Comment: Try adding this to your preamble: `\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{8000}`.

Comment: Dear Bernard, thanks for your help, but this command line works only for some URLs.

Comment: It doesn't work with all urls with a large amount of consecutive digits?

Comment: Yes, but not with all URLs.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code+ the problematic bibliography items?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Have a look at this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47267/3235

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the code. Can you please complete it with the bib entries that don't work?

Comment: You can also try to change the values of `biburlucpenalty` and `biburllcpenalty`, see also [URL line breaks with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22854/35864). If you want us to investigate your special problem, please show us the code for some of the problematic `.bib` entries as well. And make sure that the problematic URLs actually have the problem in the MWE. That way we can be sure to talk about the same thing.

Comment: See also [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191/35864), [Avoiding inelegant splits on URLs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30857/35864)

Answer (score 3):

Because we have no bib entrys you use I simply used the example bib file `biblatex-examples.bib`.  The bib entrys `kastenholz,sigfridsson,ctan,markey` have dois and urls included to test the code.

To get a better layout add the three following lines to your code:

```
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{8000} % <=================================
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}  % <=================================
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{8000}  % <=================================
```

You can change the number `8000` as you need (1 to 10000).

With the following MWE I have no problems with the margins and dois or urls:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Hsi_JACS_1975, 
  author = {Edward Hsi and Robert G. Bryant}, 
  title = {Nuclear magnetic resonance relaxation in frozen lysozyme solutions}, 
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.}, 
  year = {1975}, 
  volume = {97}, 
  number = {11}, 
  pages = {3220--3221}, 
  doi = {10.1021/ja00844a051}, 
  eprint = {dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00844a051}, 
  url = {dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00844a051}, 
}
@Article{Brovchenko_ChemPhysChem_2008, 
  author = {Ivan Brovchenko and Alla Oleinikova}, 
  title = {Multiple Phases of Liquid Water}, 
  journal = {Chem\-PhysChem}, 
  year = {2008}, 
  volume = {9}, 
  number = {18}, 
  pages = {2660--2675}, 
  issn = {1439-7641}, 
  doi = {10.1002/cphc.200800639}, 
  keywords = {percolation, phase diagrams, phase transitions, 
      supercritical fluids, thermodynamics}, 
  publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag}, 
  url = {dx.doi.org/10.1002/cphc.200800639}, 
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex,
  style=phys,
  biblabel=brackets,
  natbib=true,
  sorting=none,
  url=true,
  hyperref=auto
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{8000} % <=================================
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}  % <=================================
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{8000}  % <=================================


\begin{document}

Test \cite{kastenholz,sigfridsson,ctan,markey} 
test \cite{Hsi_JACS_1975,Brovchenko_ChemPhysChem_2008} test

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

with the resulting page:

[image: bibliography]

Please try this MWE with your own bib entrys. If you still have problems please add theese bib entrys to your question.  Then we can test them on our computers ...

Comment: Here the word "lysozyme" goes out the margins!

Comment: @Article{Brovchenko_ChemPhysChem_2008,
  author    = {Ivan Brovchenko and Alla Oleinikova},
  title     = {Multiple Phases of Liquid Water},
  journal   = {ChemPhysChem},
  year      = {2008},
  volume    = {9},
  number    = {18},
  pages     = {2660--2675},
  issn      = {1439-7641},
  doi       = {10.1002/cphc.200800639},
  keywords  = {percolation, phase diagrams, phase transitions, supercritical fluids, thermodynamics},
  publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cphc.200800639},
}