# Link "size" is wrong when compiling with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, line-breaking, ocg

Here's my requirements:

1. I need to use XeTeX.
2. I need to have links, so I'm using `hyperref`
3. I need links to be black when printing, so I'm using option `ocgcolorlinks` with hyperref
4. I need the links in the toc to be breakable, so I'm using `ocgx2` instead of the hyperref option, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361453/4888).

So far, so complicated. I then compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
%\hypersetup{pdfhighlight=/N}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long section}
\end{document}
```

If I compile with XeTex, within Acrobat reader, when clicked, the link "inverts" to a square wich looks about the size of the page ([pdf](https://github.com/agrahn/ocgx2/files/1293505/toctest.pdfxelatex.pdf)).

If instead I compile with LaTeX, within Acrobat reader, when clicked, the link "inverts" to the regular link size as it should ([pdf](https://github.com/agrahn/ocgx2/files/1293504/toctest.pdflatex.pdf)).

I can't attach any meaningful screenshots, as the inverted link doesn't show in them.

Is there any way to fix this? At first I didn't even notice this, because it doesn't happen in the TeXWorks preview. I tried using `\hypersetup{pdfhighlight=/N}`, but it either has no effect when compiling with XeTex, or is overridden/not respected by `ocgx2`.

Output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   ocgx2.sty    2017/06/08 v0.29 ports `ocgx' functionality to dvips+ps2pdf, xe
latex and dvipdfmx
  xparse.sty    2017/07/19 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2017/07/19 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/07/19 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
l3keys2e.sty    2017/07/19 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
 ocgbase.sty    2017/03/30 v0.10 support package for ocgx2.sty
 pdfbase.sty    2017/08/25 v0.17 driver independent access to low-level PDF fea
tures
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/
JK)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
 toctest.out
 toctest.out
se-ascii-print.def    2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
 ***********
```

Comment: There is no need for a long url. Already with `\url{short}` xdvipdfms warns about "Annotation out of page boundary.". Write to the author of ocgx2.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I have only recently switched to TeXWorks and have yet to get accustomed to it's log display, otherwise I might have noticed that ...

Comment: Added an issue to [github](https://github.com/agrahn/ocgx2/issues/6) ...

Comment: A quick fiddling about with [`ocgx2.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2/ocgx2.sty) seems to suggest to me that ll. 763-767 cause the problem: they create a box of size `2\paperwidth`x`2\paperheight`, which is roughly the wrong link size XeTeX produces. If these lines are removed, the links have the expected size instead. I do not currently understand the purpose of this box, so removing it might have some unexpected consequences that I am not aware of, but it at least seems like a good starting point for a more thorough investigation.

Comment: @diabonas Thanks for this, I tried to comment those lines and it now works. I have added your hint to the github issue as well.

Comment: @diabonas : This was introduced to prevent empty links from flooding the page with link colour when using `ocgcolorlinks` option (see [Ben Lerners original code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47309) ). (Try `\href{https://ctan.org}{\quad}`). Also see my comment on [GitHub](https://github.com/agrahn/ocgx2/issues/6#issuecomment-329215386) . The current GitHub version removes this safety measure for xetex.

Comment: @AlexG Ah ok, I see your point, although I do not seem to be able to replicate the effect you describe with TeX Live 2017 and Acrobat Reader DC. Thanks for the explanation and the quick fix!

Comment: You could, for instance, compile the code example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361453 with XeLaTeX, of course using the current `ocgx2.sty`, `ocgbase.sty` versions from GitHub to see the effect.

Comment: @AlexG Ah right, now I can replicate the issue, maybe I did not compile often enough last time for a stable output. Yeah, that is quite impressive, I can see why you would want to avoid that ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem it addresses has been solved by a package update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package version 0.30 containing the fix by diabonas is already available at [github](https://github.com/agrahn/ocgx2), and according to agrahn's comments there it's [already on the way to CTAN](https://github.com/agrahn/ocgx2/issues/6#issuecomment-329496861), so it'll also be available [there](https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2) soon.

Comment: I think we should close this topic. This is the usual procedure here for questions that become obsolete by a package update.

Comment: @AlexG Fine by me ...