# Handling _ in macros

Tags: macros

So I have a big number of figures with _ in their names. I want to include them in my document and I want to print the filename for the file. Something like:

```
\foreach \dataset in {CPD, EPAFHM, FDA, cas_N6512, cox2, dhfr, screen_U251} {
    \foreach \height in {0,1,2,3,4,5} {
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{heatmaps/\dataset\height Bit.pdf}
            AUC for bit fingerprint of height \height for dataset \dataset.
            \end{minipage}
    }
}
```

It works great for the graphics but of course the `_` should really be `\_` when it comes to printing. How can I fix this? I have looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment) but it does not seem to be quite the same thing.

Also, if I try the `underscore` package it works for the text but not for the graphics.

Comment: Note that `\height` is somewhat reserved...

Comment: Change `\dataset\height` into `\detokenize\expandafter{\dataset}\height` (but it's also best to use a different macro name than `\height`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graphics package itself when printing filenames with the `info` option uses

```
       \edef\@tempa{#3}%
       \rlap{ \ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@tempa}%
```

so you could do

```
\makeatletter
\def\showfilename#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
   \texttt{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@tempa}}%
\makeatother
```

use as `\showfilename{\dataset}`

Answer (score 6):

Under the `T1` font encoding, `\detokenize` will allow you to print the underscore:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\def\dataset{xyz_123}
\begin{document}
\detokenize{abc_123} \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\dataset}
\end{document}
```