# How to escape underscores in the resulting .pdf_tex file?

Tags: svg, inkscape

According to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107/41370
I have to use inkscape to generate a PDF file and a corresponding .pdf_tex file.

Since my original SVG file contains a class diagram it has many identifiers like "size_t" with underscores I get many errors.

When using the proposed statement to include the graphics it says:
Missing $ ....
for the line:

```
    \put(0.00768156,0.29678743){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{+ prepareSpawns(parent : Task*, count : std::size_t)}}}%
```

How can the underscores in the generated file be replaced?

edit:
Using Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939

Comment: Hi. Do you want the text to read size_t or size underscore t. For the first you need to use `size\_t`, while the second should be `size$_{\text{t}}$` in the Inkscape string.

Comment: The first version but if I would edit it manually it wouldn't make sense since the file is generated as well as the UML diagram from which the SVG file comes from.

Comment: Sounds like a find all `_` in inkscape of type `text` and the `Extensions->Text->Replace text...` with `_` and `\_` should fix it.

Comment: where is the definition of `\put` located?  it might be possible to redefine `_` *within* that definition to be just an ordinary character, if no other use of `_` will be made in an argument to `\put`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to fix this myself, but ended up needing some help over on: [svg package \includesvg with underscores in sgv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348298/svg-package-includesvg-with-underscores-in-sgv), which allows me to provide you this solution:

1. Define a custom macro called `\escapeus` (from [Define an "escape underscore" environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment))
2. Wrap your `\includesvg` command in the `\escapeus` command

Ex:

```
% The custom \escapeus macro to escape underscores:
\makeatletter
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\escapeus}[1]{%
        \begingroup\@activeus\scantokens{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
    \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}
\makeatother

\begin{figure}
    \centering % Make it look nice in the center
    % Wrap your \includesvg in the custom macro to escape the underscores
    \escapeus{\includesvg{mysvgfile}}
\end{figure}
```