# svg package \includesvg with underscores in svg

Tags: svg, inkscape, underscore

I have an SVG file that includes text with underscores. 
When I include the svg with the \includesvg command (from svg package), I get an error that results from the .pdf_tex file containing text with the un-escaped special character in it.

The diagram shows variable names etc so the underscores need to be there.

I'm trying to implement the advice from the answer to the question: [Define an "escape underscore" environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment), and pass in the escape to the pretex argument defined int he svg package documentation.

First, I have the svg package included in my header:

```
\usepackage{svg}
```

Then, declare the custom macro and pass it into the \includesvg command thusly:

```
% The custom \escapeus macro from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\escapeus}[1]{%
    \begingroup\@activeus\scantokens{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}
\makeatother

\begin{figure}
    \centering % Make it look nice in the center
    % Pass in the custom macro to the svg environment
    \includesvg[pretex=\escapeus]{mysvgfile}
\end{figure}
```

When I use the code as shown above, I get several errors:

```
File ended while scanning use of \@import ...retex=\escapeus]{mysvgfile}
Missing $ inserted ...retex=\escapeus]{mysvgfile}
Extra }, or forgotten $ ...retex=\escapeus]{mysvgfile}
Extra }, or forgotten $ ...retex=\escapeus]{mysvgfile}
Missing $ inserted \end{figure}
Missing } inserted \end{figure}
Missing } inserted \end{figure}
....
```

If someone can tell me what I'm missing I would really appreciate it.

This is basically a follow-up on the question: [How to escape underscores in the resulting .pdf_tex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237691/how-to-escape-underscores-in-the-resulting-pdf-tex-file) which I attempted to answer with this partial solution, and another user suggested that I ask this as a new question since I just can't get this to work and there was no activity on the other question one for a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my amazement it was as easy as changing `\includesvg[pretex=\escapeus]{mysvgfile}` to `\escapeus{\includesvg{mysvgfile}}`.

`\escapeus` expects to be passed some TeX as #1, on which it operates to remove the underscores. You can see by feeding it an empty argument `{}` that the errors above are removed, only to be replaced by the original error when the underscore is encountered.  However the `\escapeus` command can handle being passed the entire result of the `\includesvg` command.

Comment: I wonder if a tweak along these lines should be built in to the `svg` package.  I also wonder (and will test) what happens if the svg contains subscripts.

Comment: Apparently inkscape's pdf+latex export routine can't deal with subscripts anyway -- test<sub>subscript</sub> ends up as testsubscript -- so this doesn't cause any new problems.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the parameter `inkscapelatex=false`. This will tell LaTeX not to render the text.

So this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false, width=\linewidth]{pic}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{img:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Source: [package documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf)

Comment: Although not specifically what I was asking, this is another option to avoid the problem to start with, and was something else I needed to do in other places where you actually had the fonts in the SVG that you wanted, and didn't want LaTeX "helping" you by re-formatting your nice SVG at all.