# Escaped characters in labels

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I am writing some API documentation, and since I don't like to repeat myself I would like to make some commands and call those for parts that get repeated a lot. However, I am having trouble with characters that need to be escaped in some commands, while they can't be escaped in labels.

I have the following command:

```
\newcommand{\CommandHeader}[1]
{
    \subsection{#1}
    \label{command:#1}

    \subsubsection*{Name}
    #1
}
```

This works file when I call the command without any special characters

```
\CommandHeader{ping}
```

But when I call it with escaped characters, it will result in errors:

```
\CommandHeader{get\_file} % Gives missing/extra \endcsname errors
\CommandHeader{get_file} % Gives errors everywhere else
```

So my question is, how do I create a command to which I can pass a name with escaped characters, that works with both types of commands. Also, why is there a difference between these commands anyway?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you need other special characters or just `_`?

Comment: I would simply define the macro to have two arguments, one for the name and one for the label. More advanced would be a setup with an optional argument which you can use when things have to be escaped.

Comment: @egreg Just `_` for now, but since it's API documentation I can imagine this issue coming up with other characters at some point. So I would prefer a generic solution.

Comment: The solution in the answer to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment) question should be easily adaptable.

Comment: the usage in `\label` and `\section` is completely different, while it is possible to make things work (especially for `_` which is easier than accented letters) it is probably a mistake to do so and the arguments should be kept separate. The argument of `\section` is a string to be _typeset_ in the output, the argument to `\label` is essentially an internal command name used for cross referencing so you can not use `\_` for the same reason you can not use `\_` in the middle of a counter or environment name. Also unrelated but you are missing `%` from several lines in your definition.

Comment: Is there any news here?