# "escape underscore" environment with csvreader

Tags: csv

I want to put the content of a csv file in a `tabular` environment. However, this includes text with underscores "_". Because this triggers the math environment, it gives the error: `Missing $ inserted`.

Using [escape underscore](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/define-an-escape-underscore-environment) to show the actual text does not work, since then the csv reader does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\UScore{\urlstyle{rm}}
% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists3.csv}
name
Albert_Einstein,
Marie_Curie,
Thomas_Edison
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \csvreader[tabular=|l|,
  table head=\textbf{ Reference} \\\hline,
  late after line = \\\hline]%
    {scientists3.csv}{name=\name}%
    {\UScore{\name}}%
\end{document}
```

The result is obviously: "`\name`" instead of the content of the .csv file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to expand twice `\name`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name
Albert_Einstein
Marie_Curie
Thomas_Edison
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{url}

\DeclareUrlCommand\UScore{\urlstyle{rm}}
\newcommand{\expUScore}{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \UScore
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
  tabular=|l|,
  table head=\hline\textbf{Reference} \\\hline,
  late after line = \\\hline
]{\jobname.csv}{name=\name}
 {\expUScore{\name}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\jobname` to avoid clobbering my files.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use `respect underscore=true` option:

```
\csvreader[respect underscore=true,...]
```

See the [csvsimple's documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf):

> If this key is set, every underscore sign "_" inside the CSV content
>   is a normal character.