# Weird Missing $ inserted error

Tags: math-mode, symbols

This is what I wrote in my `.tex` file:

```
<\emph{Technician, View, Business_Plan, NULL}>$\rightarrow$ \emph{Deny}
<\emph{HR, View, Business_Plan, NULL}>$\rightarrow$ \emph{Deny}
<\emph{Manager, View, Business_Plan, NULL}>$\rightarrow$ \emph{Permit}
```

However, I got following compiling mistake:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.303 ...ph{Technician, View, Business_Plan, NULL}
                                                  >$\rightarrow$ \emph{Deny}...

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

I am almost mad by this weird error!!! 
Could anybody help me??

Comment: the ">" is the problematic character. it should either be gone or also placed in the $$ equation (you can't simply write > in text)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But after trying what you said(I just let the '>' go), the error still...

Comment: Because, similarly, there are more of those < and > characters appearing in text.

Comment: Try enclosing the, such that $<$ and $>$

Comment: \emph{Technician, View, Business_Plan, NULL}$\rightarrow$ \emph{Deny}
\emph{HR, View, Business_Plan, NULL}$\rightarrow$ \emph{Deny}
\emph{Manager, View, Business_Plan, NULL}$\rightarrow$ \emph{Permit}

Comment: See my code above, any problem there? But the error is still there...

Comment: The underscores `_` also have to be escaped (`\_`). It then works (in Business_Plan, that is). Welcome to the "wonderful" world of latex.

Comment: Please read _any_ introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply use "<" and ">" in text, one option would be to use `$<$` and `$>$`.

Also, underscores can't appear in text, escape these: `\_`.

Comment: Ah!That`s the point!Thank you very much.

Comment: The use of `<` and `>` is fine in text (using the correct encoding). See [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (`¡`) or question mark (`¿`)?](http://goo.gl/itXfwX) The underscore *is* the problem, which is solved [Underscore in words](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764).

Comment: @werner Perhaps add it as an answer, it is more correct/complete than this one.