# table in LaTeX giving error

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to create the table using the below script and its giving this error

> ```
> "! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text> $ l.689 \end{tabularx}"
> ```

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*2{>{\centering\hsize=1.6666\hsize}X|}*8{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.83333\hsize}X|}}
\hline
{\bf Point of Comparison} & {\bf X} & {\bf Y} & {\bf Z} & {\bf Average_entropy} & {\bf TC & {\bf RT}\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{specs}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Remove the empty line before `\hline` and add the missing closing bracket after `{\bf TC`. That should help. As well, please don't use `\bf`: all two-letter font commands have been obsolate for years. Use `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: Actually, the true problem is the `_` in `Average_entropy`. Change it to `Average entropy`. The problems I mentioned before would show up later, so you need to correct them as well.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscore-in-words

Comment: @tohecz thanks this really helped me! I just have one more question. Now the columns width is not well organized, where some coloumns has small number of letters in but its width is big and others has couple of words and its width is small which makes it use an extra line. So, if you could advise how to organize the width of the columns to fit the text in and also still be in the \linewidth ? Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you seek? How many columns do you have? 7 or 10. I do 10 in the final output. For 7 columns, you need to redo the `\hsize` calculation.  The missing dollar sign error is due to this `Average_entropy`. I have changed it to a single dash.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*2{>{\centering\hsize=1.6666\hsize}X|}*8{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.83333\hsize}X|}}
\hline\hline
{\bf Point of Comparison} & {\bf X} & {\bf Y} & {\bf Z} & {\bf Average-entropy} & {\bf TC} & {\bf RT} &&&\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{specs}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```