# Problems with itemize

Tags: math-mode, itemize

I had the following situation

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[(A_s)] Item (A_s) such that 
\begin{equation}\label{sob}
\sum_{n}n
\end{equation}
\item[(B_s)] Item (B_s)
\end{itemize}
```

and the result was blank screen. After that I put `$` at the beginning and end of the items

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[$(A_s)$] Item (A_s) such that 
\begin{equation}\label{sob}
\sum_{n}n
\end{equation}
\item[$(B_s)$] Item (B_s)
\end{itemize}
```

and everything worked fine. 
I lost a lot of time until I found this.
What was the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

`_` is a special character that denotes the beginning of a subscript, and that is only allowed in math-mode. As such, inserting `$` *around* the math-related content, the problem is avoided.

The `equation` environment automatically initiates math-mode, so there's no additional need to enter math-mode.

If you actually want an underscore, then you can use any of the methods below. Also see [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[$(A_s)$] Item ($A_s$) such that 
    \begin{equation}\label{sob}
      \sum_{n}n
    \end{equation}
  \item[$(B_s)$] Item ($B_s$)
  \item[(C\string_s)] Item (\detokenize{C_s}) and (C\textunderscore s)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Inputting `C\_s`, i.e., "escaping" the `_` character, works too.