# Adding graphics and fixing reference problems

Tags: formatting, moderncv, cv

I have two problems  in a academic resume. First attach  a  picture on the top right and second fixing some  problems in references. [image]

The template can be found in [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-banking)

the code is given here:

```
    %% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}  

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvline[]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{References}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}%
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}%
    }

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: Replace `picture` by some `\includegraphics{file.jpg}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I've added the necessary `\photo` content to `\maketitle` to insert it to the right of the regular title. You may have to adjust the `\raisebox` quantity depending on the image size you're including:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
     \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
     %\hfil%
     \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
       \centering%
       % name and title
       \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
       \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
       % detailed information
       \addressfont\color{color2}%
       \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
         \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
         \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
         \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%
       \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
         \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
       \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
       \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
       \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
         \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
       \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
       \flushmaketitle}%
       \hfill%
       \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
       \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+2\baselineskip}{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}% Insert photo
       \\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Just remove the optional argument of `\cvline` in `\cvdoublecolumn`:

   ```
   \newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
     \cvline{}{%
       \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
       \hfill%
       \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
       }%
   }
   ```

Here is complete minimal example:

[image]

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  %\hfil%
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}%
    \hfill%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
    \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+2\baselineskip}{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}% Insert photo
    \\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother



% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}  

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvline{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{References}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}%
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}%
    }

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: @warner, when I write any email using the subscript ,  like,  ehsan_milon@yahoo.com  in the reference site  it  breaks after the subscript. How to fix it?

Comment: @ComplexGuy: Use `\detokenize{<email address>}`, as suggested in [Underscores in words (text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139980/5764).