# Command \color already defined

Tags: macros, code

I have the following code in my latex command .

```
\newcommand{\color}[1]{\lceil (#1+2)^2/2\rceil}
```

After that I have inserted the following command for insertion of code in LATEX documents .

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true
  tabsize=3
}
```

But TEXMAKER compiler shows me error that command `\color` is already defined. Why does compiler show error for insertion of these code ? Can you suggest me an way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please post a MWE, not just a fragment. But in this case, `\color` is already defined by the package `color` or `xcolor` which is either included by you or by another package you used. If you explicitly want the command `\color` as in your example, you must redefine it via `\renewcommand`, but I **do not** recommend this. Chose another command name instead, please

Comment: The short answer: Don't define `\color`, since it is used/defined by the [`color` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/color). Strange though, your command `\color` doesn't even use anything related to colour... so why not define it as `\mycommand`?

Comment: The question is not directly connected to texmaker, since any other IDE or direct compilation on console would provide the same error message

Comment: I am using a template for my thesis . The code of that template is too bad . Thanks for your answer .

Comment: @user54714: What do you mean? You are trying to improve that template by redefinition of `\color` and other commands?

Comment: \color is defined in tht template . Now I am trying to insert the rest command given in my question .

Comment: @user54714: If the template defines `\color`, then add `\let\color\relax` immediately after loading it. Then you can go ahead and `\usepackage{color}` as you already do.

Comment: thanks warner . Can you put this command as answer ?

Comment: @user54714: In addition to Werner's recommendation: It will only work, if `\color` is defined by the template in the preamble, not in the running document body, i.e. after `\begin{document}`, since you can't use `\usepackage` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer , I have written the following code . \section{Data Structures Of Our Algorithm}
                 We have kept two arraylist named  plane_not_to_be_kept  and   plane_to_be_kept  .But the ide shows this error . "! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>" Why ?

Comment: @user54714: For that, see [Underscores in words (text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764).

Comment: @user54714: Werner already pointed to the 'underscores', but you are basically another question which is not connected to the previous error/question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems strange to define `\color` as a macro that doesn't have anything to do with setting a colour attribute. The best option here is to remove this definition by adding

```
\let\color\relax
```

before loading the [`color` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/color). Letting a macro to `\relax` frees it up, almost like it has not existed before.

Comment: if the op is focused on writing about (say) quarks, (s)he may be wanting a command to specify quark `colour` ... and hence has become confused.  so it's not _all that_ strange.

Comment: Redefining `\color` will create zillions of problems when `lstlisting` is used, of course. I consider this answer *very* wrong.

Comment: @egreg: You understand that the problem is with the template and that my answer allows `\color` to be restored by the `color` package, right?

Comment: @Werner Probably it should be clearer what the order should be, but you're right.