# To escape underscore without \verb and \texttt

Tags: typewriter, underscore

I know this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text) which implementation is about verb and \texttt such that you have something inside the phrase. 
I do not want to change the phrase at all. 
I want to have this as text in my document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
hp_feb04_macro.pdf
\end{document}
```

Unsuccessful attempts for *hp_feb04_macro.pdf*

```
\verb|hp_feb04_macro.pdf|
```

which changes the uncerscore something something else (-, I think).
And

```
\texttt{hp\_feb04\_macro.pdf}
```

which I do not like since my desktop search is then deteriorated.

**How can you have underscore in your text without \verb and \texttt?**

Comment: With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, when you copy the underscore produced by `\_`, you get an underscore.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know. But I do not want change the name "hp_feb04_macro.pdf" by any method. Putting "\" changes the name and deteriorates my search.

Comment: This is a different question! I do not want verb and nothing inside the escaped phrase.

Comment: Actually, not duplicate of the second proposed topic by Joseph, since I do not want to change the content of the text. Good idea is provided below.

Comment: Did you *look* at my answer to the duplicate question?

Comment: Yes. It partially answers my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to use your `hp_feb04_macro.pdf` in some macro, enclose the macro inside the `\startunderscoreletter` and `\stopunderscoreletter` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\startunderscoreletter}{\catcode`_ 12\relax}
\newcommand{\stopunderscoreletter}{\catcode`_ 8\relax}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\startunderscoreletter
hp_feb04_macro.pdf
\stopunderscoreletter

test math $a_i$
\end{document}
```

[image: underscore]

Comment: This is the right answer! Thank you for your answer!