# How can I write an under dash in text without invoking italics or some weird font?

Tags: italic, underscore

I would like to simply write a `_` in latex. But when I compile it is makes the text afterwards italic and weird, how can I just write an under dash?

For example:

```
\indent Locate the file in /lbne/app/forest/setup_help.txt
```

This produces "Locate the file in /lbne/app/forest/setup*help.txt*

And I want it to produce:

"Locate the file in /lbne/app/forest/setup_help.txt

Comment: Often asked question: Try: `setup\_help`. The `_` is an active character, reserved for subscripts in math mode, the literal `_` is obtained by the control symbol (as D.E. Knuth calls it) `\_`

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232188) might help too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The character `_` is an active one, reserved for math mode, beginning subscript as in `$a_{1}$` etc. The literal underscore character can be obtained without changing the font with the control symbol `\_` or using a verbatim display, however, this changes the font to typewriter `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

With \verb!\_!:

Locate the file in /lbne/app/forest/setup\_help.txt

With font change:

Locate the file in \verb!/lbne/app/forest/setup_help.txt!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For this there's also `\path` from the `url` package.